# What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?

Tags: unix, time, benchmarking

```
$ time foo
real        0m0.003s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.004s
$
```

What do `real`, `user` and `sys` mean in the output of time? Which one is meaningful when benchmarking my app?

Comment: @Casillass Real - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408981/how-cant-i-redirect-the-output-of-time-command

Comment: If your program exits that fast, none of them are meaningful, it's all just startup overhead.  If you want to measure the whole program with `time`, have it do something that will take at least a second.

Comment: It is really important to note that `time` is a bash keyword.  So typing `man time` is _not_ giving you a man page for the bash `time`, rather it is giving the man page for `/usr/bin/time`.  This has tripped me up.

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrome This tripped me up too. `help time` shows how to use bash `time`. I ended up running something like `/usr/bin/time --format "%e"`

Answer (score 2655, accepted):

**Real, User and Sys process time statistics**

One of these things is not like the other.  Real refers to actual elapsed time; User and Sys refer to CPU time used *only by the process.*

- **Real** is wall clock time - time from start to finish of the call.  This is all elapsed time including time slices used by other processes and time the process spends blocked (for example if it is waiting for I/O to complete).
- **User** is the amount of CPU time spent in user-mode code (outside the kernel) *within* the process.  This is only actual CPU time used in executing the process.  Other processes and time the process spends blocked do not count towards this figure.
- **Sys** is the amount of CPU time spent in the kernel within the process.  This means executing CPU time spent in system calls *within the kernel,* as opposed to library code, which is still running in user-space.  Like 'user', this is only CPU time used by the process.  See below for a brief description of kernel mode (also known as 'supervisor' mode) and the system call mechanism.

`User+Sys` will tell you how much actual CPU time your process used.  Note that this is across all CPUs, so if the process has multiple threads (and this process is running on a computer with more than one processor) it could potentially exceed the wall clock time reported by `Real` (which usually occurs).  Note that in the output these figures include the `User` and `Sys` time of all child processes (and their descendants) as well when they could have been collected, e.g. by `wait(2)` or `waitpid(2)`, although the underlying system calls return the statistics for the process and its children separately.

**Origins of the statistics reported by `time (1)`**

The statistics reported by `time` are gathered from various system calls.  'User' and 'Sys' come from [`wait (2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5168/wait-3c.html#scrolltoc) ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html)) or [`times (2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/times) ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/times.html)), depending on the particular system.  'Real' is calculated from a start and end time gathered from the [`gettimeofday (2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) call.  Depending on the version of the system, various other statistics such as the number of context switches may also be gathered by `time`.

On a multi-processor machine, a multi-threaded process or a process forking children could have an elapsed time smaller than the total CPU time - as different threads or processes may run in parallel.  Also, the time statistics reported come from different origins, so times recorded for very short running tasks may be subject to rounding errors, as the example given by the original poster shows.

**A brief primer on Kernel vs. User mode**

On Unix, or any protected-memory operating system, ['Kernel' or 'Supervisor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_mode#Supervisor_mode) mode refers to a [privileged mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_management_(computing)#Processor_modes) that the CPU can operate in.  Certain privileged actions that could affect security or stability can only be done when the CPU is operating in this mode; these actions are not available to application code.  An example of such an action might be manipulation of the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) to gain access to the address space of another process.  Normally, [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) code cannot do this (with good reason), although it can request [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) from the kernel, which *could* be read or written by more than one process.  In this case, the shared memory is explicitly requested from the kernel through a secure mechanism and both processes have to explicitly attach to it in order to use it.

The privileged mode is usually referred to as 'kernel' mode because the kernel is executed by the CPU running in this mode.  In order to switch to kernel mode you have to issue a specific instruction (often called a [*trap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(computing))) that switches the CPU to running in kernel mode *and runs code from a specific location held in a jump table.*  For security reasons, you cannot switch to kernel mode and execute arbitrary code - the traps are managed through a table of addresses that cannot be written to unless the CPU is running in supervisor mode.  You trap with an explicit trap number and the address is looked up in the jump table; the kernel has a finite number of controlled entry points.

The 'system' calls in the C library (particularly those described in Section 2 of the man pages) have a user-mode component, which is what you actually call from your C program.  Behind the scenes, they may issue one or more system calls to the kernel to do specific services such as I/O, but they still also have code running in user-mode.  It is also quite possible to directly issue a trap to kernel mode from any user space code if desired, although you may need to write a snippet of assembly language to set up the registers correctly for the call.

**More about 'sys'**

There are things that your code cannot do from user mode - things like allocating memory or accessing hardware (HDD, network, etc.). These are under the supervision of the kernel, and it alone can do them. Some operations like `malloc` or`fread`/`fwrite` will invoke these kernel functions and that then will count as 'sys' time. Unfortunately it's not as simple as "every call to malloc will be counted in 'sys' time". The call to `malloc` will do some processing of its own (still counted in 'user' time) and then somewhere along the way it may call the function in kernel (counted in 'sys' time). After returning from the kernel call, there will be some more time in 'user' and then `malloc` will return to your code. As for when the switch happens, and how much of it is spent in kernel mode... you cannot say. It depends on the implementation of the library. Also, other seemingly innocent functions might also use `malloc` and the like in the background, which will again have some time in 'sys' then.

Comment: Does the time spent by child processes count into real/sys?

Comment: @ron - According to the Linux man page, it aggregates the 'c' times with the process times, so I think it does. The parent times and child times are available separately from the times(2) call, though. I guess the Solaris/SysV version of time(1) does something similar.

Comment: @ron I've just edited the answer: The time spent by child processes and their descendants count *only* when the time could have been collected by wait(2) or waitpid(2), and recursively with descendants. This implies that the child processes must have terminated. For instance, compare `time sh -c 'foo & sleep 1'` and `time sh -c 'foo & sleep 2'`, where `foo` is a command that takes CPU time between 1 and 2 seconds. The former outputs something around 0.

Comment: User+Sys lets you measure CPU usage of a process.  You can use it to benchmark performance.  This is particularly useful for multi-threaded code where more than one CPU core might be working on a computation.

Comment: Not precisely on topic, nevertheless:
Running "\time <cmd>" is interesting - it provides more detail: (forgive poor formatting in the comment):
$ time ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9437 pts/19   00:00:00 bash
11459 pts/19   00:00:00 ps

real 0m0.025s
user 0m0.004s
sys 0m0.018s
$ \time ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9437 pts/19   00:00:00 bash
11461 pts/19   00:00:00 time
11462 pts/19   00:00:00 ps
0.00user 0.01system 0:00.02elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2160maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+103minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$

Comment: (Ran out of chars in the prev comment so):
More detail? Use perf [1], [2].
[1] https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page
[2] http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: Is there a simple way of finding out how the "Real" time is spent? Like, is it more time on network I/O than on disc I/O?

Comment: @Gunnar 'Real' time can be spent on other processes, so there isn't any way using these calls to ascertain what the computer was doing.  You can get stats using the process accounting system on most unix systems, which may tell you useful information.  Top (1) goes through kernel data structures via /dev/kmem to get its data.

Comment: I find that sometimes the User + Sys does not equal real time. What would cause this? Also how does this generalise to GPU computation?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the post discusses the relationship between user, sys and real in some detail.  GPU time is not counted in process stats as far as I'm aware, as calls out to the GPU will either block the process (forcing a context switch) or will be non-blocking, in which case the process will continue and the system will measure the CPU time used by the process.  You will need GPU-specific benchmarking tools to measure how much GPU time is being used by the process.

Comment: Nice. Where did you get these details from?

Comment: Most of it is in the man page for time(1).  The rest I learned from an operating systems course at university.  There are books (e.g. Bach or Stevens) that cover this material.

Comment: Shouldn't be real >= user+sys always?

Comment: Not necessarily the case on multiprocessor machines.  Multiple threads can rack up more CPU time than elapsed time.

Comment: “various other statistics such as the number of context switches may also be gathered by time.”  yes this is true. Add time.sleep(0) in to a large loop to test this, both the user and sys time increased

Answer (score 373):

To expand on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/1677912), I just wanted to provide another reason why `real` ≠ `user` + `sys`.

Keep in mind that `real` represents actual elapsed time, while `user` and `sys` values represent CPU execution time. As a result, on a multicore system, the `user` and/or `sys` time (as well as their sum) can actually *exceed* the real time. For example, on a Java app I'm running for class I get this set of values:

```
real    1m47.363s
user    2m41.318s
sys     0m4.013s
```

Comment: I'd always wondered about this. Since I know that my programs are single threaded, the difference between user and real time must be VM overhead, correct?

Comment: not necessarily; the Sun JVM on Solaris machines as well as Apple's JVM on Mac OS X manages to use more than one core even in single-threaded apps. If you do a sample of a java process, you'll see that things like garbage collection run on separate threads (and some other stuff too that I don't remember off the top of my head). I don't know if you really want to term that "VM overhead" though.

Comment: @Quantum7 - no, not necessarily.  See my post above.  Real is elapsed time, user and sys are accumulated time slice statistics from the CPU time the process actually uses.

Comment: I guess the amount of up-votes gave you enough reputation now :D. So what do you think about `real` exceeding `user` and `sys` total ? OS overhead such as thread context switching may be ?

Comment: Context switching would add that much additional runtime only if you had a multithreaded application that was in reality running serially (i.e. due to locks). A single-threaded application (truly single-threaded, which the JVM isn't as we saw above) would also give you a similar result.

Comment: Another potential issue could be I/O: if your application spends a good deal of time waiting to receive a file or stream, then obviously the real time would greatly exceed the user/sys time because no CPU time is used while waiting to get access to a file or something similar.

Comment: I'd love to find out why people are sometimes down voting this answer. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I came across this GC outputs. Its intuitive to say real = usr + sys but it is not always the case. This is also answered here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40694/why-real-time-can-be-lower-than-user-time

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana It's not necessarily overhead at all. When the computer is hit with timer interrupts it'll decide to swap over to some daemons to keep them running, X11 to keep your windowing smooth, and then back to your process, in a fraction of a second. Most of that time will not be overhead, but still be time spent. appx <1% of that lost time will be "sys" time from other processes, so that'll be OS overhead like context switching, which counts towards real but not user/sys of the running process. Most of (real - (user+sys)) will be other program's "user" time however.

Answer (score 84):

• **real**: The actual time spent in running the process from start to finish, as if it was measured by a human with a stopwatch

• **user**: The cumulative time spent by all the CPUs during the computation

• **sys**: The cumulative time spent by all the CPUs during system-related tasks such as memory allocation.

> Notice that sometimes user + sys might be greater than real, as
>   multiple processors may work in parallel.

Comment: `real` is often described as "wall-clock" time.

Comment: Or in my case, sometimes `real` is more than the `user+sys`, for me it is due to running so many parallel processes at once.  
    87.02 real        14.12 user         5.20 sys  
    41.30 real         7.03 user         3.20 sys  
    2387.46 real       750.67 user       282.80 sys  
    2.60 real         7.22 user         3.35 sys

Answer (score 65):

**Minimal runnable POSIX C examples**

To make things more concrete, I want to exemplify a few extreme cases of `time` with some minimal C test programs.

All programs can be compiled and run with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -o main.out -pthread -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra main.c
time ./main.out
```

and have been tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0, glibc 2.28, Linux kernel 4.18, ThinkPad P51 laptop, Intel Core i7-7820HQ CPU (4 cores / 8 threads), 2x Samsung M471A2K43BB1-CRC RAM (2x 16GiB).

**`sleep` syscall**

Non-busy sleep as done by the `sleep` syscall only counts in `real`, but not for `user` or `sys`.

For example, a program that sleeps for a second:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    sleep(1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/164bf9459c519d6c696e4318df62fceab8735320/posix/interactive/sleep_1.c).

outputs something like:

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

The same holds for programs blocked on IO becoming available.

For example, the following program waits for the user to enter a character and press enter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%c\n", getchar());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/164bf9459c519d6c696e4318df62fceab8735320/c/interactive/getchar.c).

And if you wait for about one second, it outputs just like the sleep example something like:

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

For this reason `time` can help you distinguish between CPU and IO bound programs: [What do the terms "CPU bound" and "I/O bound" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean/33510470#33510470)

**Multiple threads**

The following example does `niters` iterations of useless purely CPU-bound work on `nthreads` threads:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint64_t niters;

void* my_thread(void *arg) {
    uint64_t *argument, i, result;
    argument = (uint64_t *)arg;
    result = *argument;
    for (i = 0; i < niters; ++i) {
        result = (result * result) - (3 * result) + 1;
    }
    *argument = result;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t nthreads;
    pthread_t *threads;
    uint64_t rc, i, *thread_args;

    /* CLI args. */
    if (argc > 1) {
        niters = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        niters = 1000000000;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        nthreads = strtoll(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nthreads = 1;
    }
    threads = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(*threads));
    thread_args = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(*thread_args));

    /* Create all threads */
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        thread_args[i] = i;
        rc = pthread_create(
            &threads[i],
            NULL,
            my_thread,
            (void*)&thread_args[i]
        );
        assert(rc == 0);
    }

    /* Wait for all threads to complete */
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        assert(rc == 0);
        printf("%" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 "\n", i, thread_args[i]);
    }

    free(threads);
    free(thread_args);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream + plot code](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/4ec6412223bcaeea48128e0dd0e11f9f320aefba/posix/interactive/pthread_cpu_heavy_work.c).

Then we plot wall, user and sys as a function of the number of threads for a fixed 10^10 iterations on my 8 hyperthread CPU:

[image]

[Plot data](https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/24a8298a741c3c903a5551aa0740e43c#file-pthread_cpu_heavy_work-dat).

From the graph, we see that:

- for a CPU intensive single core application, wall and user are about the same
- for 2 cores, user is about 2x wall, which means that the user time is counted across all threads.

  user basically doubled, and while wall stayed the same.
- this continues up to 8 threads, which matches my number of hyperthreads in my computer.

  After 8, wall starts to increase as well, because we don't have any extra CPUs to put more work in a given amount of time!

  The ratio plateaus at this point.

Note that this graph is only so clear and simple because the work is purely CPU-bound: if it were memory bound, then we would get a fall in performance much earlier with less cores because the memory accesses would be a bottleneck as shown at [What do the terms "CPU bound" and "I/O bound" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean/33510470#33510470)

Quickly checking that wall < user is a simple way to determine that a program is multithreaded, and the closer that ratio is to the number of cores, the more effective the parallelization is, e.g.:

- multithreaded linkers: [Can gcc use multiple cores when linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142753/can-gcc-use-multiple-cores-when-linking/64128746#64128746)
- C++ parallel sort: [Are C++17 Parallel Algorithms implemented already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060/are-c17-parallel-algorithms-implemented-already/55989883#55989883)

**Sys heavy work with `sendfile`**

The heaviest sys workload I could come up with was to use the `sendfile`, which does a file copy operation on kernel space: [Copy a file in a sane, safe and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-a-sane-safe-and-efficient-way)

So I imagined that this in-kernel `memcpy` will be a CPU intensive operation.

First I initialize a large 10GiB random file with:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sendfile.in.tmp bs=1K count=10M
```

Then run the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *source_path, *dest_path;
    int source, dest;
    struct stat stat_source;
    if (argc > 1) {
        source_path = argv[1];
    } else {
        source_path = "sendfile.in.tmp";
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        dest_path = argv[2];
    } else {
        dest_path = "sendfile.out.tmp";
    }
    source = open(source_path, O_RDONLY);
    assert(source != -1);
    dest = open(dest_path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    assert(dest != -1);
    assert(fstat(source, &stat_source) != -1);
    assert(sendfile(dest, source, 0, stat_source.st_size) != -1);
    assert(close(source) != -1);
    assert(close(dest) != -1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/164bf9459c519d6c696e4318df62fceab8735320/glibc/sendfile.c).

which gives basically mostly system time as expected:

```
real    0m2.175s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m1.476s
```

I was also curious to see if `time` would distinguish between syscalls of different processes, so I tried:

```
time ./sendfile.out sendfile.in1.tmp sendfile.out1.tmp &
time ./sendfile.out sendfile.in2.tmp sendfile.out2.tmp &
```

And the result was:

```
real    0m3.651s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m1.516s

real    0m4.948s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m1.562s
```

The sys time is about the same for both as for a single process, but the wall time is larger because the processes are competing for disk read access likely.

So it seems that it does in fact account for which process started a given kernel work.

**Bash source code**

When you do just `time <cmd>` on Ubuntu, it uses the Bash keyword as can be seen from:

```
type time
```

which outputs:

```
time is a shell keyword
```

So we grep source in the Bash 4.19 source code for the output string:

```
git grep '"user\b'
```

which leads us to [execute_cmd.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=b0776d8c49ab4310fa056ce1033985996c5b9807#n1299) function `time_command`, which uses:

- `gettimeofday()` and `getrusage()` if both are available
- `times()` otherwise

all of which are [Linux system calls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) and [POSIX functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html).

**GNU Coreutils source code**

If we call it as:

```
/usr/bin/time
```

then it uses the GNU Coreutils implementation.

This one is a bit more complex, but the relevant source seems to be at [resuse.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=time.git;a=blob;f=resuse.c;h=41339418a278f0ef66913117964b6d65e836a8f3;hb=ad3684f72903e3720ef3620a422c7989628f2354#l68) and it does:

- a non-POSIX BSD `wait3` call if that is available
- `times` and `gettimeofday` otherwise

**Related questions**

- multithreaded linkers: [Can gcc use multiple cores when linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142753/can-gcc-use-multiple-cores-when-linking/64128746#64128746)
- C++ parallel sort: [Are C++17 Parallel Algorithms implemented already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060/are-c17-parallel-algorithms-implemented-already/55989883#55989883)

Answer (score 17):

Real shows total turn-around time for a process;
while User shows the execution time for user-defined instructions
and Sys is for time for executing system calls!

Real time includes the waiting time also (the waiting time for I/O etc.)

Answer (score 16):

In very simple terms, I like to think about it like this:

- `real` is the actual amount of time it took to run the command (as if you had timed it with a stopwatch)
- `user` and `sys` are how much 'work' the `CPU` had to do to execute the command.  This 'work' is expressed in units of time.

Generally speaking:

- `user` is how much work the `CPU` did to run to run the command's code
- `sys` is how much work the `CPU` had to do to handle 'system overhead' type tasks (such as allocating memory, file I/O, ect.) in order to support the running command

Since these last two times are counting 'work' done, they don't include time a thread might have spent waiting (such as waiting on another process or for disk I/O to finish).

`real`, however, is a measure of actual runtime and not 'work', so it *does* include any time spent waiting (which is why sometimes `real > usr+sys`).

And finally, sometimes the reverse is true (`usr+sys > real`) for multi-threaded applications.  This also arises because we are comparing 'work-time' to actual time.  For example, if 3 processors each run continuously for 10 minutes to execute a command, you will get `real = 10m` but `usr = 30m`.

Answer (score 4):

I want to mention some other scenario when the real-time is much much bigger than user + sys. I've created a simple server which respondes after a long time

```
real 4.784
user 0.01s
sys  0.01s
```

the issue is that in this scenario the process waits for the response which is not on the user site nor in the system.

Something similar happens when you run the `find` command. In that case, the time is spent mostly on requesting and getting a response from SSD.

Answer (score -4):

Must mention that at least on my AMD Ryzen CPU,  the `user` is always large than `real` in multi-threaded program(or single threaded program compiled with `-O3`).

eg.

```
real    0m5.815s
user    0m8.213s
sys 0m0.473s
```

Comment: You could write a multi-threaded program the threads spent most of their time sleeping (e.g. for multi-threaded I/O), in which case the total CPU-seconds of user time would likely be lower than the wall-clock "real time".  But yes, on a system with multiple cores, any CPU-intensive multi-threaded program will normally use more than 1 CPU-second per second of real time.  That's kind of the point.  The graphs in [Ciro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/53937376#53937376) show user time scaling with threads.

Comment: I wrote a single threaded C program and compile with -O3 , then the `real` time will smaller than `user` , I just have ryzen cpu no intel cpus.

Comment: AMD and Intel CPUs aren't different for this.  Not sure what your point is with that or the single-threaded test.  Yes, of course a single-threaded program will have user+sys <= real, that's guaranteed.  But it's also *possible* for a multi-threaded program to have that, if the threads all spend a lot of their time asleep, like waiting for I/O.  e.g. a multi-threaded web server that isn't very busy.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, sorry, I misread your previous comment.  That's not normal unless your compiler auto-parallelizes, which GCC doesn't do by default.  (Only if you manually enable `-ftree-parallelize-loops=4` like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment-with-compiler-optimization-disabl) or use `#pragma omp parallel for ...` + `-fopenmp`.)

Comment: An actual single-threaded program will always have `user + sys <= real`, I'm pretty sure.  If it's higher, that means it's using multiple threads. (Or if real is lower by a tiny amount, like a millisecond, it could just be timing granularity like not using up a full tick interval, or getting charged more user time than you actually used if the rounding error goes the other way.)