# What's the difference between "C system calls" and "C library routines"?

Tags: c, unix, system, manpage

There are multiple sections in the manpages. Two of them are:

```
2     Unix and C system calls
3     C Library routines for C programs
```

For example there is [`getmntinfo(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getmntinfo.3.html) and [`getfsstat(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getfsstat.2.html), both look like they do the same thing. When should one use which and what is the difference?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

System calls are operating system functions, like on UNIX, the [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) function is built on top of the [`sbrk()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) system call (for resizing process memory space).

Libraries are just application code that's not part of the operating system and will often be available on more than one OS.  They're basically the same as function calls within your own program.

The line can be a little blurry but just view system calls as kernel-level functionality.

Answer (score 15):

Libraries of common functions are built on top of the system call interface, but applications are free to use both.

System calls are like authentication keys which have the access to use kernel resources.

[image]

Above image is from Advanced Linux programming and helps to understand how the user apps interact with kernel.

Answer (score 12):

System calls are the interface between user-level code and the kernel.  C Library routines are library calls like any other, they just happen to be really commonly provided (pretty much universally).  A lot of standard library routines are wrappers (thin or otherwise) around system calls, which does tend to blur the line a bit.

As to which one to use, as a general rule, use the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 6):

The calls described in section 2 of the manual are all relatively thin wrappers around actual calls to system services that trap to the kernel.  The C standard library routines described in section 3 of the manual are client-side library functions that may or may not actually use system calls.

[This posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) has a description of system calls and trapping to the kernel (in a slightly different context) and explains the underlying mechanism behind system calls with some references.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, you should always use the C library version.  They often have wrappers that handle esoteric things like restarts on a signal (if you have requested that).  This is especially true if you have already linked with the library.  All rules have reasons to be broken. Reasons to use the direct calls,

1. You want to be `libc` agnostic; Maybe with an installer.  Such code could run on Android ([bionic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29)), [uClibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uclibc), and more traditional glibc/eglibc systems, regardless of the library used.  Also, dynamic loading with wrappers to make a run-time glibc/bionic layer allowing a dual Android/Linux binary.
2. You need extreme performance. Although this is probably rare and most likely misguided.  Probably rethinking the problem will give better performance benefits and **not** calling the system is often a performance win, which the `libc` can occasionally do.
3. You are writing some `initramfs` or `init` code without a library; to create a smaller image or boot faster.
4. You are testing a new kernel/platform and don't want to complicate life with a full blown file system; very similar to the `initramfs`.
5. You wish to do something very quickly on program startup, but eventually want to use the `libc` routines.
6. To avoid a known bug in the `libc`.
7. The functionality is not available through `libc`.

Sorry, most of the examples are Linux specific, but the rationals should apply to other Unix variants.  The last item is quite common when new features are introduced into a kernel.  For example when [`kqueue`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) or [`epoll`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) where first introduced, there was no `libc` to support them.  This may also happen if the system has an older library, but a newer kernel and you wish to use this functionality.

If your process hasn't used the `libc`, then most likely something in the system will have.  By coding your own variants, you can negate the cache by providing two paths to the same end goal.  Also, Unix
will share the code pages between processes.  Generally there is no reason not to use the `libc` version.

Other answers have already done a stellar job on the difference between `libc` and system calls.