# stat64 system call: how many parameters?

Tags: posix, stat

On OSX 10.9 (a 64 bit OS) I run the command

```
sudo dtruss pwd
```

to get the list of system calls performed by the pwd command.
I see that the system call stat64 is executed several times like this:

```
stat64("/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5F7B4E28, 0x7FFF5F7B5CC0)       = 0 0
```

Now, in both the online POSIX standard documentation and [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat64.2.html), I see that stat64 takes 2 parameters.
Why does it take 3 parameters in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *C* library call `stat64` is just a [wrapper](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch01lev1sec11.html)(*[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572942/whats-the-difference-between-c-system-calls-and-c-library-routines)*) around the [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). They don't have to match in the number of arguments although in the case of [linux](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) for example it seems like they mostly do(*I can't find a similar reference for BSD*), although a notable exception would be [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) which is implemented as a call to the clone system call.

**Update**

I can not find the equivalent for OSX but if we look at the [syscalls man page for Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) is says:

> Over time, changes to the interfaces of some system calls have been
>          necessary.  One reason for such changes was the need to increase the
>          size of structures or scalar values passed to the system call.
>          Because of these changes, there are now various groups of related
>          system calls (e.g., truncate(2) and truncate64(2)) which perform
>          similar tasks, but which vary in details such as the size of their
>          arguments.  (As noted earlier, applications are generally unaware of
>          this: the glibc wrapper functions do some work to ensure that the
>          right system call is invoked, and that ABI compatibility is preserved
>          for old binaries.)  Examples of systems calls that exist in multiple
>          versions are the following:

Comment: This is definitely a good point, but still there is something that escapes me. According to 'man dtruss', the dtruss command shows details of the system calls, so stat64 system call seems to take 3 arguments; but according to 'man 2 stat', stat and stat64 system calls (section 2 of man is about system calls) take only 2 arguments. Which one is lying? Or rather: what am I missing here? Moreover section 3 of man (which is about C library functions) doesn't contain a page about stat/stat64 (but this could be just a shortcoming of the manual itself).

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior updated my answer, I did not receive a notification of your comment, which is odd.