# How can I select a static library to be linked while ARM cross compiling?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I have an ARM cross compiler in Ubuntu(arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc) and the default archtecture is ARMv7.  However, I want to compile an ARMv5 binary. I do this by giving the compiler the `-march=armv5te` option.

So far, so good.  Since my ARM system uses BusyBox, I have to compile my binary statically linked.  So I give gcc the `-static` option.

However, I have a problem with *libc.a* which the linker links to my ARMv5 binary.  This file is compiled with the ARMv7 architecture option.  So, even if I cross-compile my ARM binary with ARMv5, I can't run it on my BusyBox based ARMv5 box.

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. Where can I get the ARMv5 *libc.a* static library, and how can I link it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices,

1. Get the right compiler.
2. Write your own 'C' Library.

### Get the right compiler.

You are **always** safest to have a compiler match your system.  This applies to x86 Linux and various distributions.  You are lucky if different compilers work.  It is more difficult when you cross-compile as often the compiler will not be automatically synced.  Try to run a program on a 1999 x86 Mandrake Linux compiled on your 2014 Ubuntu system.

As well as instruction compatibility (which you have identified), there are ABI and OS dependencies.  Specifically, the *armv7* is most likely **hardfloat** (has *floating point FPU* and register call convention) and you need a **softfloat** (emulated FPU).  The specific *glibc* (or *ucLibc*) has specific calls and expectations of the Linux OS.  For instance, the way *threads* works has changed over time.

### Write your own

You can always use `-fno-builtin` and `-ffreestanding` as well as `-static`.  Then you can not use any *libc* functions, but you can [program them your self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572942/whats-the-difference-between-c-system-calls-and-c-library-routines).

There are external source, like [Mark Martinec's snprintf](http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/) and building blocks like `write()` which is easy to implement,

```
#define _SYS_IOCTL_H 1
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
static inline int write(int fd, void *buf, int len)
{
    int rval;
        asm volatile ("mov      r0, %1\n\t"
                "mov    r1, %2\n\t"
                "mov    r2, %3\n\t"
                "mov    r7, %4\n\t"
                "swi    #0\n\t"
                "mov    %0, r0\n\t"
                : "=r" (rval)
                : "r" (fd),
                  "r" (buf),
                  "r" (len),
                  "Ir" (__NR_write)
                : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r7");
    return rval;
}

static inline void exit(int status)
{
        asm volatile ("mov      r0, %0\n\t"
                "mov    r7, %1\n\t"
                "swi    #0\n\t"
                : : "r" (status),
                  "Ir" (__NR_exit)
                : "r0", "r7");
}
```

You have to add your own start-up machinery taken care of by the 'C' library,

```
/* Called from assembler startup. */
int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
    write(STDOUT, "Hello world\n", sizeof("Hello world\n"));
    return 0;
}

/* Wrapper for main return code. */
void __attribute__ ((unused)) estart (int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int rval = main(argc,argv);
    exit(rval);
}

/* Setup arguments for estart [like main()]. */
void __attribute__ ((naked)) _start (void)
{
    asm(" sub     lr, lr, lr\n"   /* Clear the link register. */
        " ldr     r0, [sp]\n"     /* Get argc... */
        " add     r1, sp, #4\n"   /* ... and argv ... */
        " b       estart\n"       /* Let's go! */
        );
}
```

If this is too daunting, because you need to implement a lot of functionality, then you can try and get various library source and rebuild them with `-fno-builtin` and make sure that the libraries do not get linked with the Ubuntu libraries, which are incompatible.

Projects like [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) can allow you to build a correct compiler (maybe with more advanced code generation) that suits the *armv5* system exactly.  This may seem like a pain, but the alternatives above aren't easy either.

Comment: The code above is for about Linux 2.6.36 and the *EABI* syscall Linux (not *OABI*).  You have to have the Linux headers to write your own library.  `dmesg` or `cat /proc/version` should tell you your Linux version, but not the configuration.