# Cross compile for ARM926EJ-S rev 4 (v5l)

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

Hi Im having troubles to with compiling for this cpu:

```
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 4 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 199.06
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : dh-electronics PZE-TE
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

Its old RFID chip terminal and i want to write new software for it but cant even run hello world :/ 
I compile it but the board just wont run this binary file.
Can you from this information help me with flags for `gnueabi`.

The system is running Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 but I believe it is missing features, even classic stuff like apt-get doesn't work, even though it acts like Debian.

Comment: hello world is just about the most complicated program that can be run, there are so many buried layers and then that sits on some sort of operating system so what do you mean by hello world?  and why not try to blink an led first?

Comment: And hello world because its just somthing with output i can see, and also I want continue programing in c++ so get working basic code is first step ;)

Comment: maybe you need to find an old cross compiler, see if/how the output differs from a current one, perhaps the linux calling convention changed over time for example.

Comment: Related: [Select static library with ARM cross compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616226/how-can-i-select-a-static-library-to-be-linked-while-arm-cross-compiling).  I give a recipe for creating a binary that requires no external libraries.  Most linux executables are actually started by 'ld' and this has implications.  You need to match the filesystem 'libc', 'ld' and other parameters as well as Linux features (and of course the CPU but usually `gcc` will emit code safe for most everything).