# How to convert a hex float to a float in C/C++ using _mm_extract_ps SSE GCC instrinc function

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, hex, sse

I'm writing a *SSE* code to 2-D convolution but *SSE* documentation is very sparse.

I'm calculating dot-product with `_mm_dp_ps` and using `_mm_extract_ps` to get the dot-product result but `_mm_extract_ps` returns a hex `float` and I can't figure out how to convert this hex `float` to a regular `float`.

I could use `__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v4sf` that returns a `float` but I wanna keep compatibility with others compilers.

```
_mm_extract_ps (__m128 __X, const int __N)
{
  union { int i; float f; } __tmp;
  __tmp.f = __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v4sf ((__v4sf)__X, __N);
  return __tmp.i;
}
```

What point I'm missing?

A little help will be appreciated, thanks.

**OpenSUSE 11.2**, **GCC 4.4.1**, **C++**

Compiler options: `-fopenmp -Wall -O3 -msse4.1 -march=core2`

Linker options: `-lgomp -Wall -O3 -msse4.1 -march=core2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT`.

Incidentally it looks to me as if `_mm_extract_ps` and `_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT` should be the other way around, i.e. `_mm_extract_ps` should return a float and `_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT` should return the int representation, but what do I know.

Comment: I guess it's down to the way that Intel describe the instruction in their documentation, which may or may not be an error - the gcc headers just implement what is there in the documentation.

Comment: And is there an `_MM_EXTRACT_DOUBLE` of some sort?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件: see [`_mm_cvtsd_f64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1782,1788,1782,1782&text=_mm_cvtsd_f64).

Comment: `_mm_extract_ps` is the intrinsic for [SSE4.1 `extractps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/extractps), the "fp" version of `pextrd`.  dst = memory or a GP integer register, not an XMM register.  It can't extract a scalar float into a new register.  For that, use `pshufd`.  (Or `insertps` with a false dependency).  The compiler can use `extractps` to extra a float to memory, but the only use-case for the `_mm_extract_ps` intrinsic in C/C++ is getting the integer bit-pattern of a `float` into a scalar `uint32_t`.  Type punning it back to float is just asking for the compiler to emit slow code.

Answer (score 4):

`_mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(__X, __X, __N))` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

And just to exemplify all that has been mentioned so far:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>

#include <x86intrin.h>

int main(void) {

    /* 32-bit. */
    {
        __m128 x = _mm_set_ps(1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 4.5f);

        /* _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT */
        float f;
        _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(f, x, 3);
        assert(f == 1.5f);
        _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(f, x, 2);
        assert(f == 2.5f);
        _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(f, x, 1);
        assert(f == 3.5f);
        _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(f, x, 0);
        assert(f == 4.5f);

        /* _mm_cvtss_f32 + _mm_shuffle_ps */
        assert(_mm_cvtss_f32(x) == 4.5f);
        assert(_mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(x, x, 1)) == 3.5f);
        assert(_mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(x, x, 2)) == 2.5f);
        assert(_mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(x, x, 3)) == 1.5f);
    }

    /* 64-bit. */
    {
        __m128d x = _mm_set_pd(1.5, 2.5);
        /* _mm_cvtsd_f64 + _mm_unpackhi_pd */
        assert(_mm_cvtsd_f64(x) == 2.5);
        assert(_mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(x, x)) == 1.5);
    }
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/26183613e5683212d4a31b9aad033966a9e7e84b/userland/arch/x86_64/intrinsics/addpd.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

Doubles mentioned at: [_mm_cvtsd_f64 analogon for higher order floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359372/mm-cvtsd-f64-analogon-for-higher-order-floating-point)

Tested on Ubuntu 19.04 amd64.

Answer (score 0):

extern void _mm_store_ss(float*, __m128);

See 'xmmintrin.h.'