# Intel SSE: Why does `_mm_extract_ps` return `int` instead of `float`?

Tags: c, sse, simd

Why does `_mm_extract_ps` return an `int` instead of a `float`?

What's the proper way to read a single `float` from an XMM register in C?

Or rather, a different way to ask it is: *What's the opposite of the `_mm_set_ps` instruction?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a hex float to a float in C/C++ using _mm_extract_ps SSE GCC instrinc function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130169/how-to-convert-a-hex-float-to-a-float-in-c-c-using-mm-extract-ps-sse-gcc-instr)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130169/how-to-convert-a-hex-float-to-a-float-in-c-c-using-mm-extract-ps-sse-gcc-inst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514058.aspx), I believe you can cast the result to a float.

Note from their example, the 0xc0a40000 value is equivalent to -5.125 (a.m128_f32[1]).

Update: I strongly recommend the answers from @doug65536 and @PeterCordes (below) in lieu of mine, which apparently generates poorly performing code on many compilers.

Comment: What kind of a cast would it be, though? A C-style cast wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Sure - as long as the storage size matches.  BTW - looks like there's a macro that may help: _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130169/how-to-convert-a-hex-float-to-a-float-in-c-c-using-mm-extract-ps-sse-gcc-instr )

Comment: Ahhhhhhh that's precisely solution for the problem I was facing!! It's hard to search for; thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Don't type-pun the result of `_mm_extract_ps` back to `float`.  That's not what the intrinsic is for, and ICC or GCC end up making code that ranges from bad to horrible when you do this.  See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526658/intel-sse-why-does-mm-extract-ps-return-int-instead-of-float/41191977#41191977) for asm output from some simple test cases on Godbolt.  With the correct and safe union-based type-punning that @Apriori suggested, though, gcc makes good code in both cases.  It's only ICC that has a problem.

Answer (score 22):

None of the answers appear to actually answer the question, *why* does it return `int`.

The reason is, the `extractps` instruction actually copies a component of the vector to a general register. It does seem pretty silly for it to return an int but that's what's actually happening - the raw floating point value ends up in a general register (which hold integers).

If your compiler is configured to generate SSE for all floating point operations, then the closest thing to "extracting" a value to a register would be to shuffle the value into the low component of the vector, then cast it to a scalar float. This should cause that component of the vector to remain in an SSE register:

```
/* returns the second component of the vector */
float foo(__m128 b)
{
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(b, b, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 2)));
}
```

The `_mm_cvtss_f32` intrinsic is free, it does not generate instructions, it only makes the compiler reinterpret the xmm register as a `float` so it can be returned as such.

The `_mm_shuffle_ps` gets the desired value into the lowest component. The `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro generates an immediate operand for the resulting `shufps` instruction.

The `2` in the example gets the float from bit 95:64 of the 127:0 register (the 3rd 32 bit component from the beginning, in memory order) and places it in the 31:0 component of the register (the beginning, in memory order).

The resulting generated code will most likely return the value naturally in a register, like any other floating point value return, with no inefficient writing out to memory and reading it back.

If you're generating code that uses the x87 FPU for floating point (for normal C code that isn't SSE optimized), this would probably result in inefficient code being generated - the compiler would probably store out the component of the SSE vector then use `fld` to read it back into the x87 register stack. In general 64-bit platforms don't use x87 (they use SSE for all floating point, mostly scalar instructions unless the compiler is vectorizing).

I should add that I always use C++, so I'm not sure whether it is more efficient to pass __m128 by value or by pointer in C. In C++ I would use a `const __m128 &` and this kind of code would be in a header, so the compiler can inline.

Comment: `movss xmm, xmm` doesn't zero the upper components.  It leaves them unchanged.  Maybe you'd thinking of integer `movd xmm, r32` or `movd xmm, m32`.  Also, that _MM_SHUFFLE turns a vector of `{ d c b a }` into `{ a a a c }`.  It puts the 3rd element into the low32, not the 2nd, unless you're counting from the high end...

Comment: @PeterCordes Fixed and clarified the shuffle, thanks.

Comment: Saying that `_mm_cvtss_f32` "is free (no asm instructions)" might be a clearer way to express the fact that it's effect is like a reinterpret_cast of the XMM register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I added my own answer with some more thoughts about Intel's design choices (and a warning not to type-pun `_mm_extract_ps` back to float, because that's not what it's for).  Your shuffle is the correct way to express this, and compilers (other than ICC) do optimize that to `extractps [mem], xmm0, 2` when appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

**Confusingly, `int _mm_extract_ps()` is not for getting a scalar `float` element from a vector.**  The intrinsic doesn't expose the memory-destination form of the instruction (which can be useful for that purpose).  This is not the only case where the intrinsics can't directly express everything an instruction is useful for. :(

gcc and clang know how the asm instruction works and will use it that way for you when compiling other shuffles; type-punning the `_mm_extract_ps` result to `float` usually results in horrible asm from gcc (`extractps eax, xmm0, 2` / `mov [mem], eax`).

The name makes sense if you think of `_mm_extract_ps` as extracting an [IEEE 754 binary32 float bit pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) out of the FP domain of the CPU into the integer domain (as a C scalar `int`), instead of manipulating FP bit patterns with integer vector ops.  **According to my testing with gcc, clang, and icc (see below), this is the only "portable" use-case where `_mm_extract_ps` compiles into good asm across all compilers**.  Anything else is just a compiler-specific hack to get the asm you want.

---

The corresponding asm instruction is [`EXTRACTPS r/m32, xmm, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/EXTRACTPS.html).  Notice that the destination can be memory or an *integer* register, but not another XMM register.  It's the FP equivalent of [`PEXTRD r/m32, xmm, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRB:PEXTRD:PEXTRQ.html) (also in SSE4.1), where the integer-register-destination form is more obviously useful.  EXTRACTPS is not the reverse of [`INSERTPS xmm1, xmm2/m32, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INSERTPS.html).

Perhaps this similarity with PEXTRD makes the internal implementation simpler without hurting the extract-to-memory use-case (for asm, not intrinsics), or maybe the SSE4.1 designers at Intel thought it was actually more useful this way than as a non-destructive FP-domain copy-and-shuffle (which x86 seriously lacks without AVX).  There are FP-vector instructions that have an XMM source and a memory-or-xmm destination, like [`MOVSS xmm2/m32, xmm`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSS.html), so this kind of instruction would not be new.  Fun fact: the opcodes for PEXTRD and EXTRACTPS differ only in the last bit.

---

**In assembly, a scalar `float` is just the low element of an XMM register** (or 4 bytes in memory).  The upper elements of the XMM don't even have to be zeroed for instructions like [ADDSS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADDSS.html) to work without raising any extra FP exceptions.   In calling conventions that pass/return FP args in XMM registers (e.g. all the usual x86-64 ABIs), `float foo(float a)` must assume that the upper elements of XMM0 hold garbage on entry, but can leave garbage in the high elements of XMM0 on return.  ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475902/is-garbage-allowed-in-high-bits-of-parameter-and-return-value-registers-in-x86-6#comment68239948_40475902)).

[As @doug points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526658/intel-sse-why-does-mm-extract-ps-return-int-instead-of-float/17258448#17258448), other shuffle instructions can be used to get a float element of a vector into the bottom of an xmm register.  **This was already a mostly-solved problem in SSE1/SSE2**, and it seems EXTRACTPS and INSERTPS weren't trying to solve it for register operands.

---

SSE4.1 [`INSERTPS xmm1, xmm2/m32, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INSERTPS.html) is one of the best ways for compilers to implement `_mm_set_ss(function_arg)` when the scalar float is already in a register and they can't/don't optimize away zeroing the upper elements.  ([Which is most of the time for compilers other than clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)).  That linked question also further discusses the failure of intrinsics to expose the load or store versions of instructions like EXTRACTPS, INSERTPS, and PMOVZX that have a memory operand narrower than 128b (thus not requiring alignment even without AVX).  It can be impossible to write safe code that compiles as efficiently as what you can do in asm.

Without AVX 3-operand SHUFPS, x86 doesn't provide a fully efficient and general-purpose way to copy-and-shuffle an FP vector the way integer [PSHUFD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFD.html) can.  [SHUFPS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPS.html) is a different beast unless used in-place with src=dst.  Preserving the original requires a MOVAPS, which costs a uop and latency on CPUs before IvyBridge, and always costs code-size.  Using PSHUFD between FP instructions costs latency (bypass delays).  (See [this horizontal-sum answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) for some tricks, like using SSE3 MOVSHDUP).

SSE4.1 INSERTPS can extract one element into a separate register, but AFAIK it still has a dependency on the previous value of the destination even when all the original values are replaced.  False dependencies like that are bad for out-of-order execution.  [xor-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/224132) a register as a destination for INSERTPS would still be 2 uops, and have lower latency than MOVAPS+SHUFPS on SSE4.1 CPUs without mov-elimination for zero-latency MOVAPS (only Penryn, Nehalem, Sandybridge.  Also Silvermont if you include low-power CPUs).  The code-size is slightly worse, though.

---

Using `_mm_extract_ps` and then type-punning the result back to float (as suggested [in the currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526658/intel-sse-why-does-mm-extract-ps-return-int-instead-of-float/5527502#5527502) and its comments) is a bad idea.  It's easy for your code to compile to something horrible (like EXTRACTPS to memory and then load back into an XMM register) on either gcc or icc.  Clang seems to be immune to braindead behaviour and does its usual shuffle-compiling with its own choice of shuffle instructions (including appropriate use of EXTRACTPS).

I tried these examples with gcc5.4 `-O3 -msse4.1 -mtune=haswell`, clang3.8.1, and icc17, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gWwA4EsA2ApgE4A0uIEGOBJIwArACwAMpAZgQC4kDOlAIxAByFsNLVMhAHZcA8tPwBPEWNIATXMUKouuAG6F%2Bo8blmF8q4QEpS6bHvTTjAWgAeqANQuA6gEN8fG8fQjcuYj9vOQBmb0xeXkImADoARjiuAFdpQgBSaIARJD9eAHcLIJd2aXQXQ2IBdESXEswbUkthBnFpKzsRXIAmaPTS3C4kTzcADgA2F1mmT2BULwZkpnEuK2tbAGsQaMHkgHYmJkWTo6OTlhZojpFN0l6TfuFxfjZtk1s4WBQ1DwRDIFCoWGBdFQ%2BD80mA0WmqQ43D4gj6khk8kUKjemm0ugMRj6Zh4nTEtnsjmcIncXl8AUqITCESisRc8USKXS7KyOXyRRK5UC3mqtXqjWarXanW6Lz66AGw1G40mM3mi080NhwE80WS0zSWx2%2B0OKRYiwAnBbZncGLMGFaGI9hM9XmoFR9SF9SD9yaR/sg0BDaKDKECQyBcKtUidkfgeMR%2BBAhG8MbIFMo%2BnidHpDMY1CSLDs7A5cE5XB5ggzgqFwpEXDE4gkkmlvG4ABJyADKABUMtk8oVimUKiKanUSBLCC1eG1bDKevLFSNPGMJlM5gsllGvDGjb8TdE9akLfc7bMTqkWLcWEjOs9MCAGGw3eIPZ8QN9jc7BuJH3bkkGJ1X3efc/QDCBAXQdRCAAUU0Lh0FDCAACsQCRSky2pcF8HQTJiFwRIAEFZ3RYMiAUABhYo4UIYteDw4hUDo4QhmiMxoUyGDPHySjcEwTASQI6RkiQfJYNyFgiMkoiAHpZM8TJEnUTwAElKMottO17TwUKUrhPDMTUSkIQyDPUdAjGkMBhAM7QGSUTw9hqUom05NIZM8qS2NwdhPFSGT5OWVYQAEPwVM1GE4XodBoM8QyQuAWL1Bk/R0FwFTa2IAB9bJeD8dhCGyhwmJKLgIGy7LMFSQZpk8fRSE8dhcL8AyACpsGsHiTgAIRk%2BKgv0MsYR4XhPF4cIowMgJcBKMxgH6zw2ogEk2usbAeMKTwqswbKsr8XRit4CAGs8QZrHyHqBoUpAkIIgQiE1aDTPYYgsGC1BPJOAovLkhSVlQGK4si7UgYindQvC1L0sy5liuyCqqpqurTua9BWqWzrur6qTrsU6QsM8LglGwUzsGyAm4UMsb8sKwzpE8SirU8CBYRUgBxAA5ABVRnPDZzwud5yihj6wYeou3H8cJtHWvJhncl6%2BmDNwS6mpagz2DVxWCia7BLsW9hsGSXBNt1na9uZA6uCOk7GvOg2pY6s29eSLXoiu%2BK8fDIgxsQ/mGf23RsBputcGAJADP9qRMCQpQvp%2B7ypKCgGwfirVoqS4GIdu4h7qIaGMs8LLsuAaRMkR6ravqxrZfarHFZxoi8YBxTEjGoOuBD1cVX5zwY7jzwYImxqdyHyyO7hiakLyJ2Nv5ercgYHrBiXn6PYT36U5C3P89MkHM%2BS%2BKc7u3AHtnoi0qLkvp%2B0SvkZr9X0frrrG8NjWiZwJeeqYNfHeb7aAlsq30IJkW2XAcCNX0BdD2eMagGUwoJAAXoQFSfhSh%2BCUI1a2mQAjjUQtoWS2gWrqFkiAxazsF4QP1svVeDB15Nx1lvf6iUj4H1AFncGIVsCxWIIXWG4RgFIEyOwe%2B1dUYfw6q/Xqi1KpVzqoQQYLsLa8GEewZqRUQ521Og7Dec9lFANQPoLgCRsrsCOBARRMDPbby8EpIwxcrbB14JvbywwZCaC1sneSPjfF%2BP8cwj6ad2HBIhmFFKUk66eG0DbeWYiUbSKbvFbIMsNby2xsrQyasonuyujrPW/94pGxNgY3andbY6OsYtGJ%2BEGbFNya46S3igmcPTlFDhbCIacJklEmJpdy7xPqok6phAsjEAZvob%2BdCGGNMCiwwG4S2mg1aQlQG3TIkfz6SAwZEjn6Y2GVLKJ1Dv6/3oYUwBu0QFgK0dQqBVSpY1PGZ/GhK8/56Okt9QJqcVkZw6dnVh0EembNGUIkROza6SIbjIqWciH6KNKaC9RRAKmkEqecx5DMLZGJMbwMxFirFq08LYtuDjO4h0adKEQspXipDfCIEW4tRbjUYsxHiSowI2HnE8P8IAmB6hOMBJcnpvS%2Bk5aQA4V4WDJDuDK2VsqHidGiIuN474fTfnqLwLCvKgA%3D%3D%3D).  I used C mode, not C++, but union-based type punning is allowed in GNU C++ as an extension to ISO C++.  Pointer-casting for type-punning violates strict aliasing in C99 and C++, even with GNU extensions.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

// gcc:bad  clang:good  icc:good
void extr_unsafe_ptrcast(__m128 v, float *p) {
  // violates strict aliasing
  *(int*)p = _mm_extract_ps(v, 2);
}

  gcc:   # others extractps with a memory dest
    extractps       eax, xmm0, 2
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    ret


// gcc:good  clang:good  icc:bad
void extr_pun(__m128 v, float *p) {
  // union type punning is safe in C99 (and GNU C and GNU C++)
  union floatpun { int i; float f; } fp;
  fp.i = _mm_extract_ps(v, 2);
  *p = fp.f;     // compiles to an extractps straight to memory
}

   icc:
    vextractps eax, xmm0, 2
    mov       DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    ret       


// gcc:good  clang:good  icc:horrible
void extr_gnu(__m128 v, float *p) {
  // gcc uses extractps with a memory dest, icc does extr_store
  *p = v[2];
}

 gcc/clang:
    extractps       DWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0, 2
 icc:
    vmovups   XMMWORD PTR [-24+rsp], xmm0
    mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-16+rsp]      # reload from red-zone tmp buffer
    mov       DWORD PTR [rdi], eax

// gcc:good  clang:good  icc:poor
void extr_shuf(__m128 v, float *p) {
  __m128 e2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(v,v, 2);
  *p = _mm_cvtss_f32(e2);  // gcc uses extractps
}

 icc:   (others: extractps right to memory)
    vshufps   xmm1, xmm0, xmm0, 2
    vmovss    DWORD PTR [rdi], xmm1
```

**When you want the final result in an xmm register, it's up to the compiler to optimize away your extractps and do something completely different.  Gcc and clang both succeed, but ICC doesn't.**

```
// gcc:good  clang:good  icc:bad
float ret_pun(__m128 v) {
  union floatpun { int i; float f; } fp;
  fp.i = _mm_extract_ps(v, 2);
  return fp.f;
}

  gcc:
    unpckhps        xmm0, xmm0
  clang:
    shufpd  xmm0, xmm0, 1
  icc17:
    vextractps DWORD PTR [-8+rsp], xmm0, 2
    vmovss    xmm0, DWORD PTR [-8+rsp]
```

Note that icc did poorly for `extr_pun`, too, so it doesn't like union-based type-punning for this.

**The clear winner here is doing the shuffle "manually" with `_mm_shuffle_ps(v,v, 2)`, and using `_mm_cvtss_f32`.**  We got optimal code from every compiler for both register and memory destinations, except for ICC which failed to use EXTRACTPS for the memory-dest case.  With AVX, SHUFPS + separate store is still only 2 uops on Intel CPUs, just larger code size and needs a tmp register.  Without AVX, though, it would cost a MOVAPS to not destroy the original vector :/

---

According to [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), all Intel CPUs except Nehalem implement the register-destination versions of both PEXTRD and EXTRACTPS with multiple uops:  Usually just a shuffle uop + a MOVD uop to move data from the vector domain to gp-integer.  Nehalem register-destination EXTRACTPS is 1 uop for port 5, with 1+2 cycle latency (1 + bypass delay).

I have no idea why they managed to implement EXTRACTPS as a single uop but not PEXTRD (which is 2 uops, and runs in 2+1 cycle latency).  Nehalem MOVD is 1 uop (and runs on any ALU port), with 1+1 cycle latency. (The +1 is for the bypass delay between vec-int and general-purpose integer regs, I think).

Nehalem cares a lot of about vector FP vs. integer domains; SnB-family CPUs have smaller (sometimes zero) bypass delay latencies between domains.

The memory-dest versions of PEXTRD and EXTRACTPS are both 2 uops on Nehalem.

On Broadwell and later, memory-destination EXTRACTPS and PEXTRD are 2 uops, but on Sandybridge through Haswell, memory-destination EXTRACTPS is 3 uops.  Memory-destination PEXTRD is 2 uops on everything except Sandybridge, where it's 3.  This seems odd, and Agner Fog's tables do sometimes have errors, but it's possible.  Micro-fusion doesn't work with some instructions on some microarchitectures.

If either instruction had turned out to be extremely useful for anything important (e.g. inside inner loops), CPU designers would build execution units that could do the whole thing as one uop (or maybe 2 for the memory-dest).  But that potentially requires more bits in the internal uop format (which Sandybridge simplified).

Fun fact: `_mm_extract_epi32(vec, 0)` compiles (on most compilers) to `movd eax, xmm0` which is shorter and faster than `pextrd eax, xmm0, 0`.

Interestingly, [they perform differently on Nehalem](http://agner.org/optimize/) (which cares a lot of about vector FP vs. integer domains, and came out soon after SSE4.1 was introduced in Penryn (45nm Core2)).  EXTRACTPS with a register destination is 1 uop, with 1+2 cycle latency (the +2 from a bypass delay between FP and integer domain).  PEXTRD is 2 uops, and runs in 2+1 cycle latency.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`_mm_storeu_ps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44e30x22.aspx), or any of the variations of [SSE store operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybhzf6dk.aspx).