# How to split an XMM 128-bit register into two 64-bit integer registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

How to split a 128-bit `xmm` register into two 64-bit quadwords?

I have a very large number in `xmm1` and want to get the higher quadword to `r9` and lower quadword to `r10`, or `RAX` and `RDX`.

`movlpd` or `movhpd` only works with reg to mem or vice versa.

Comment: Compile `long long f(long long __attribute__((vector_size(16))) x){return x[1];}` with gcc (and the version with `0`) to get some suggestions...

Answer (score 8):

SSE2 (baseline for x86-64) has instructions for moving data directly between XMM and integer registers (without bouncing through memory).  It's easy for the low element of a vector: [MOVD or MOVQ](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVD:MOVQ.html).  To extract higher elements, you can just shuffle the element you want down to the low element of a vector.

SSE4.1 also added insert/extract for sizes other than 16-bit (e.g. [PEXTRQ](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRB:PEXTRD:PEXTRQ.html)).  Other than code-size, it's [not actually faster than a separate shuffle and movq on any existing CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526658/intel-sse-why-does-mm-extract-ps-return-int-instead-of-float/41191977#41191977), but it means you don't need any extra tmp registers.

```
#SSE4.1
movq    rax, xmm0       # low qword
pextrq  rdx,  xmm0, 1   # high qword
# 128b result in rdx:rax, ready for use with div r64 for example.
# (But watch out for #DE on overflow)
# also ready for returning as a __int128_t in the SystemV x86-64 ABI

#SSE2
movq       r10, xmm0
punpckhqdq xmm0, xmm0    # broadcast the high half of xmm0 to both halves
movq       r9,  xmm0
```

PUNPCKHQDQ is the most efficient way to do this.  It's fast even on old CPUs with slow shuffles for element-sizes smaller than 64-bit, like 65nm Core2 (Merom/Conroe).  See [my horizontal sum answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132) for more details about that.  PUNPCKHQDQ doesn't have an immediate operand, and is only SSE2, so it's only 4 bytes of code-size.

To preserve the original value of xmm0, use `pshufd` with a different destination.  Or to swap high and low halves in-place, or whatever.

---

> movlpd or movhpd ...

There's no point in ever using them.  Use movlps / movhps instead, because they're shorter and no CPUs care about float vs. double.

You can use [`movhlps xmm1, xmm0`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVHLPS.html) to extract the high half of xmm0 into another register, but mixing FP shuffles with integer-vector operations will cause bypass delays on some CPUs (specifically Intel Nehalem).  Also beware of the dependency on xmm1 causing a latency bottleneck.

Definitely prefer `pshufd` for this in general.  But you could use `movhlps` if you're tuning for a specific CPU like Core2 where `movhlps` is fast and runs in the integer domain, and `pshufd` is slow.