# _mm_cvtsd_f64 analogon for higher order floating point

Tags: c++, c, performance, simd, intrinsics

I'm playing around with SIMD and wonder why there is no analogon to _mm_cvtsd_f64 to extrat the higher order floating point from a __m128d.

GCC 4.6+ has an extension which achieves this in a nice way:

```
__m128d a = ...;
double d1 = a[0];
double d2 = a[1];
```

But on older GCC (i.e 4.4.) the only way I could manage to get this is to define my own analogon function using __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2df, i.e.:

```
extern __inline double __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm_cvtsd_f64_h (__m128d __A)
{
  return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2df (__A, 1);
}

__m128d a = ...;
double d1 = _mm_cvtsd_f64(a);
double d2 = _mm_cvtsd_f64_h(a);
```

Is this really the way to go? Is there any alternative that does not use potentially compiler-specific __builtin stuff? And again - why is there no _mm_cvtsd_f64_h or similar predefined?

This alternative I could come up with is much slower btw:

```
_mm_cvtsd_f64_h(__m128d __A) {
    double d[2];
    _mm_store_pd(d, __A);
    return d[1];
}
```

Comment: MOVHPD, _mm_storeh_pd() intrinsic ought to work.

Comment: I tested Hans suggestion with both MS and gcc compilers and it generates the simplest code I believe.

Comment: I also just tested it in my code but _mm_storeh_pd seems to be a few percent slower, i.e. between the accepted answer below but faster than my bad _mm_cvtsd_f64_h approach above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you use the following code:

```
inline static _mm_cvtsd_f64_h(__m128d x) {
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(x, x));
}
```

This is likely the fastest way to get get the upper half of `xmm` register, and it is compatible with MSVC/icc/gcc/clang.

Comment: Thank you - works like a charm and is just as fast as the builtin version I posted above!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a union:

```
union {
    __m128d v;
    double a[2];
} U;
```

Assign your __m128d to U.v and read back U.a[0] or U.a[1]. Any decent compiler will optimise away redundant stores and loads.

Comment: Clear case of UB

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: in theory, yes, but in practice it’s such a common usage that compilers tend to generate correct code for it (or optimise it away completely, where possible).

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012491/253056), and particularly [@mafso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741125/mafso)’s comment below it.