# Efficiently extract single double element from AVX-512 vector

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx512

I was wondering what the most efficient way is to extract a single double element from an AVX-512 vector without spilling it, using intrinsics.

Currently i'm doing a masked reduce add:

```
double extract(int idx, __m512d v){
    __mmask8 mask = _mm512_int2mask(1 << idx);
    return _mm512_mask_reduce_add_pd(mask, v);
}
```

I can't imagine that this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce_add` isn't a hardware instruction, it's a helper function that does a whole chain of shuffles and adds!

A vector with the element you want as the low element is the same thing as a scalar `double`;  `double _mm512_cvtsd_f64(__m512d)` is free so you really just need a way to get the element you want to the bottom.

---

If you had a mask to start with, [`vcompresspd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcompresspd) (`_mm512_maskz_compress_pd`) would be a good option, 2 uops on Intel and Zen 4.  (https://uops.info/)

---

But you have an integer index to start with, so you can use that as as a shuffle-control vector to get the element you want to the low element of a vector.  e.g. you want the compiler to do something like `vmovd xmm1, edi` / `vpermpd zmm0,zmm,zmm` for this function.

As an extension, GNU C allows `return v[idx]`.  Agner Fog's [VectorClass library](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2) in C++ overloads `operator[]` to also work that way, generating a shuffle for you to keep MSVC happy.

You can do it manually, assuming the index isn't a compile-time constant, with `vpermpd`.  (For a known-constant index, other shuffles might be even more efficient, like AVX2 `vpermpd ymm, ymm, imm8` if the element number happens to be in the low 4, or a 128-bit-granularity immediate shuffle if the element number is 2, 4, or 6, otherwise `valignq dst, same,same, imm8`.)

```
double extract512(int idx, __m512d v)
{
#ifdef __GNUC__
    return v[idx];  // let the compiler optimize it, in case of compile-time constant index or vector
#else
    __m512i shuf = _mm512_castsi128_si512( _mm_cvtsi32_si128(idx) );  // vmovd
    return _mm512_cvtsd_f64( _mm512_permutexvar_pd(shuf, v) );        // vpermpd
#endif
}
```

Interestingly, gcc and clang both choose to store/reload after aligning the stack, taking advantage of store-forwarding from an aligned 64-byte store to an 8-byte aligned reload.  ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhAAZgBWUgAHVAVCWwZnNw89eMSbAV9/IJZQ8OiLTCtshiECJmICVPdPLhKy5MrqglzAkLDImIUqmrr0xr62jvzCnoBKC1RXYmR2DgBSACYIv2Q3LABqJYjHPBYWPwJiPwA6BD3sJY0AQVu79Fng%2Bm3MVVOmayiuFYgTts8OhVKRtqYWL8VuhtgA3SaPJYAdgAQoi1ngqNssDR/OgIKYAOIBOSOUwI%2B7bKnbYiYAhzBhwpZRFHA1TMgAiexRVIA9LztvQCNsCAhMNs0CxYnQwttULEbMcAF7iwhgvwSphKOVYyXS%2BgAWkV4rQDBGgiBDCwqjlxDhmGsJHREVKSke1PBxkhfzw2wUCFcWL2HPBRyhxlEfUSfwAHMZElCIKGWBHYQREhEVvG8LGASDJtsEREedt%2BXCWKhYeh3dTafTiIyvd6s8g0wp0MYqAA2SRJpvh2JhFiuAgfWHVYyxfH%2BwNg%2BGF7kej1l2GD4hS6v3VYuq2YxFIrlb%2B7PVyvcUfL4/P5ewyuMQAi1ssEQqEw%2BH7tGU6kvn1%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%2B0545nsiZJ6ujjBLgc5IIy6RF7HgD32EDaoWN68On7/knrWO%2BYrvXeglYB6ryHl9K2x1YaL0Bp/R2YMZ7d2hr3cegMAErzNlxS%2Bm9Rp4BkrvaacJXAMFiMgWmksYSkyriTXmZCNCv0bgQLgLdNbQJ1rress8e6JkaCgtew8G6gL6FwRBDCp4wNYXA%2Be153b3k4V7IBaDBoCkchlWINC%2BEEA0EIr%2BzDf4H17hAHaMjUEqNHmowRUDQbYVgX/cB8NAb6NQqgjg0xaCcCiLwTwHAtCkFQJwDSCh04LF2GsHgpACCaEcdMWmkQuznCiFEGMPYACcGguAxiRH8BJ/dnEcEkG4sJXjOC8AUCANaoSPGONIHAWAMAoDVIgEgPUMoyAUAgA0%2Bg4RkB3y4F2DQa0sCwl6pgAAah1YSAB5Qc7jgk0FoKZIpEBgh5OCH4ao%2BlODBKWcwYg%2BlRnBG0A6UpwTJShwIKMhgBk8lYDhsAcQZTSD4FpNYPAj8im3I%2BA6PyazeAnFKHkySwRHpbOcFgT5ISzgsE%2BdMGKTBgAKGGZgMZEyQX8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6hbm6EaAYIwIBTARn0HgYIRTIDTEyhFTgBpRkRG2AaAA6npJlI15hXEAkqBgj9iA5KaPs5I9grSDAaKQHwUlxjdEaJkJIAgxUZASPKhgYwujhGGKUIVAhWgDBcPUPQlhtUVH6O0KV6rDWmsVcMU1aqCgyumH4uYCw9DCUMCchUABJBg/AIX6Bcbk253iOAk3iQaHsEpCWeS6ecDQsb7K4EIFfbcXBJi8FKVoSY0wxRMCwOECAESQCSASTEtYMYNAJKiGWitVauz%2BuybwcFURJDnAiJIYtKwNARAiBk7tSJpDuM8cGwpxSQlhOmJUxAKBUBSkaeQSgrTujIGAH8ABfSBlwoRYwJFdBZmUAWbcjZKyQVHq2TsvZ1gQVHM6qc85tzLmpRuZ4%2B5Qrnl5LecgD53AvmCB%2Bbcv5AL9JAsWME04hw/VQphZu8Z27v2YuEKIcQGLkXyCUGoPJugAFRuJWYMlFL4DUrzrSjg9LGUsrZey6o3VgyqDDT2A0sIBVGseXYCADhrUSqtHaiYsrlXlA43K8o3GZWCpYyatoHHmPlF1WavIFqbUSf1UMCwtrzX2o1Y6/x6LSBusEOMgg3rfXfqcQG0gg7eDBtDV2cNXNgAdO2H8c4xMICJqIHaFNaax1lKzaQHNebKCFqiHGyQSIuxcCSSFsLEX%2B31oFeZ/JHAR0lPHSZjgKxG0gBjBEWNnasvdvy/lxo8Xh1eczRU2pSBZgEClgQedLSZ36jCAEIqnBaPWYjXfBz0S42eMwPgNzwI9AodRUh6QKHsXobxa6x6sQ/VZNcWZvJwbRkjhqynNrNnI2pS67G%2BNEBnCzraYEiIqb00pd85gXN3QC2xYyzGhJSIEldK7C917r2B1LYKRYUdGbwmkEiV2bL7auDRArTGWMSIK31oiIGodX3fs%2BayelxbQb4fnb5YkOwkggA%3D%3D%3D)).  They do compile the manual shuffle to the expected `vmovd` + `vpermpd` (or `vpermq` for clang because it loves to rewrite shuffles.)

Either option is reasonable for throughput (at least after inlining into a loop, so stack alignment doesn't have to get redone for every extract).  Modern Intel has a lot of load and store ports (2 each on Ice Lake), but only two vector ALU ports that can be active while running 512-bit uops.

The shuffle is probably lower latency from vector input to scalar output.  (And with multiple vectors using the same index, could reuse the same shuffle-control vector.)

Maybe similar latency from index input to scalar output, with `vmovd` + `vpermpd` both on the critical path adding up to something close to store-forwarding latency.

For a non-inline function, the extra work of aligning the stack is definitely not worth it.  (If they were going to store/reload in this non-inline function, they could align a pointer other than RSP into the red-zone, like `lea rax, [rsp-64]` / `and rax, -64`, no need to change RSP at all. But that would be using an unknown 64 bytes of the 128-byte red-zone, not efficient if there were any other locals.)  Store-forwarding on most CPUs works fairly well even with misaligned stores, especially when the reload is aligned *relative to the store*.

---

**Depending on surrounding code, you might choose to use the manual shuffle version.**  If you aren't sure, try both and look at the asm and/or benchmark.  For example:

```
double extract512(int idx, __m512d v)
{
#ifdef __GNUC__   // let the compiler optimize compile-time-constant shuffles after inlining
    if (__builtin_constant_p(idx)) {
        return v[idx];
    }
    // else use the intrinsics for runtime-variable shuffles.
#endif

    __m512i shuf = _mm512_castsi128_si512( _mm_cvtsi32_si128(idx) );  // vmovd
    return _mm512_cvtsd_f64( _mm512_permutexvar_pd(shuf, v) );        // vpermpd
}
```

---

#### Compile-time constant shuffles

GCC and clang code-gen for compile-time constant `idx`.  GCC generally does a very good job with `return v[idx]`, while clang sometimes mangles it or the vpermpd intrinsic to 2 shuffles.

```
// optimal is GCC's valignq zmm0,zmm0,zmm0, 7
double test7(__m512d v){         return extract512(7, v); } // using v[7]
double test7_manual(__m512d v){  return extract512_manual(7, v); } // using intrinsics
```

```
# clang 16.0 -O3 -march=znver4    same as -O3 -march=x86-64-v4
test7:                          # same code-gen for v[7] and intrinsics
        vextractf32x4   xmm0, zmm0, 3
        vpermilpd       xmm0, xmm0, 1   # quite disappointing
        vzeroupper
        ret

# GCC12.2 -O3 -march=x86-64-v4  make optimal asm for this
test7:                           # return v[7]
        valignq zmm0, zmm0, zmm0, 7
        ret                    # GCC knows the caller passed a ZMM arg and will do its own vzeroupper.

test7_manual:                    # GCC intrinsics with idx=7
        vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]  # optimized the shuffle constant down from 64 to 16 bytes, but could have used a vmovd 4-byte load
        vpermpd zmm0, zmm1, zmm0
        ret
```

Shuffles with idx from 0 to 3 present more optimization opportunities, since the data only comes from the low YMM. So we can look at AVX1 and AVX2 instructions.  idx=4 and 6 are also interesting, where the element we want is at the bottom of a 128-bit or 256-bit lane.

```
##### Clang
test4:   # clang - vextractf64x4 ymm0, zmm0, 1  (or 32x8) is much better on Zen 4 but same on Intel
        vextractf32x4   xmm0, zmm0, 2
        vzeroupper
        ret

test3:   # clang - quite inefficient
        vextractf128    xmm0, ymm0, 1
        vpermilpd       xmm0, xmm0, 1           # xmm0 = xmm0[1,0]
        vzeroupper
        ret

test2:   # clang - good
        vextractf128    xmm0, ymm0, 1
        vzeroupper
        ret

test1:  # clang - good, could save 2 bytes of code size with vmovhlps or vunpckhpd but otherwise fine
        vpermilpd       xmm0, xmm0, 1           # xmm0 = xmm0[1,0]
        vzeroupper
        ret

test0:   # clang - good
        vzeroupper
        ret

#### GCC
test4:     # GCC v[4]  : good, but vextractf64x4 ymm0, zmm0, 1  has better throughput (0.25) and latency (1c) on Zen 4
        vextractf64x2   xmm0, zmm0, 2
        ret
test3:     # GCC v[3]  : a YMM shuffle would be more efficient, especially on Zen 4, like vpermpd ymm0, ymm0, 3
        valignq zmm0, zmm0, zmm0, 3
        ret
test2:  # GCC v[2]    : Good but AVX1 vextractf128 saves a byte
        vextractf64x2   xmm0, ymm0, 1
        ret
test1:  # GCC v[1]    : Good, optimal I think.  (or maybe vshufpd for better Ice Lake throughput.)
        vunpckhpd       xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        ret
test0:  # GCC v[0]    : Obviously good.
        ret
```

GCC's `testn_manual` code-gen is always a `vmovdqa xmm` load and a `vpermpd zmm`, except for `test0_manual` where it used `vpxor   xmm1, xmm1, xmm1` to zero a shuffle-control still for `vpermpd zmm`.

---

Related, mostly SSE and AVX1/2, not AVX-512:

- [No insert and extract for float/double in SSE and AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917054/no-insert-and-extract-for-float-double-in-sse-and-avx)
- [How to get data out of AVX registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612455/how-to-get-data-out-of-avx-registers) - for SSE there was a `_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT` *CPP macro*, among other things.
- [print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable) - if you need all the elements, store to an array and index it.  Compilers often optimize this to a shuffle if you only use one element.