# How to extract a double from a vector of doubles (SIMD)?

Tags: c++, performance, simd, cpu-registers, low-level

sorry if this is a nooby question or a possible duplicate, but I am reading into vector intrinsics and thinking that is there a clean way to extract the first double out 256-bit vector of 4 doubles with C++ vector intrinsics?

I have tried reading answers in similar area but they don't seem to answer the question explicitly

Comment: `_mm256_cvtsd_f64()`? (Assuming AVX)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you! Is there a way to extract from an arbitrary index in the vector or only from the first, so to get from arbitrary I have to shuffle first?

Comment: Yes. In AVX you can use a permute if the index is not in the first lane though permute are quite expensive (permutevar for a dynamic index). You should think twice before extracting values in a code for sake of performance.

Comment: Probably better to just store into a 4 element array and choose from that.

Comment: What ISA are you talking about?  AVX isn't the only one that exists; there's also AArch64 SVE (although that's variable-length, not guaranteed 256-bit).  Anyway, tag [avx] if that's what you're using, since the details are specific to it, not to [simd] in general.

Comment: For AVX-512, with some mention of AVX2 see [Efficiently extract single double element from AVX-512 vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75997936) - `vpermpd` (`_mm256_permute4x64_pd`) + `_mm256_cvtsd_f64()` is the way to go.  See also [How to get data out of AVX registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37612455) .

Comment: If you compile with gcc or clang and don't care about compatibility, you can just use the `[]` operator, e.g. for a vector `__m256d x`, `x[0]` extracts the lowest, and `x[3]` the highest element. If you need this occasionally, just let the compiler choose whatever way it thinks is best. If you need this a lot inside a critical loop, you should consider re-designing your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you all for your enlightening questions!