# Using SSE instructions with gcc without inline assembly

Tags: c, x86-64, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am interested in using the SSE vector instructions of x86-64 with gcc and don't want to use any inline assembly for that. Is there a way I can do that in C? If so, can someone give me an example?

Comment: I have also posted some minimal intrinsics example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389712/getting-started-with-intel-x86-sse-simd-instructions/56409539#56409539

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) in the *mmintrin.h headers (`emmintrin.h`, `xmmintrin.h`, etc, depending on what level of SSE you want to use). This is generally preferable to using assembler for many reasons.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main(void)
{
    __m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(4, 3, 2, 1);
    __m128i b = _mm_set_epi32(7, 6, 5, 4);
    __m128i c = _mm_add_epi32(a, b);

    // ...
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this approach works for most x86 and x86-64 compilers on various platforms, e.g. gcc, clang and Intel's ICC on Linux/Mac OS X/Windows and even Microsoft's Visual C/C++ (Windows only, of course).

Comment: Both gcc and VC++ support the intrinsics.

Comment: FTW, icc supports these intrinsics too

Comment: Thanks - I've added a note to the answer stating that this approach is supported by most x86 C/C++ compilers.

Comment: @PaulR Even better is to include `x86intrin.h`, which pulls in all MMX/SSE/AVX and some stuff like `bswap` or `ror`, makes them available as the intrinsic functions and sets `__SSEX__` preprocessor macros according to the architecture or compiler flags given.

Comment: Is this an abstraction for ARM or x86?

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek: the question and answers are all x86/SSE-specific. ARM has a different SIMD ISA (NEON) and different intrinsics.

Comment: @GuntherPiez: `x86intrin.h` is not portable to MSVC, only GCC / clang and I think ICC.  The Intel-defined `immintrin.h` is portable across all mainstream x86 compilers that defines every Intel SIMD intrinsic.  Also, `__SSEx__` / `__AVX__` / etc. macros are pre-defined by the compiler itself, regardless of headers.  That's how the headers know which intrinsic "functions" to define.  `x86intrin.h` makes your compile times slower, which is another reason not to use if it you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 6):

Find the `*intrin.h` headers in your gcc includes (`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/include/` here).

Maybe noteworthy, the header `immintrin.h` includes all other intrins according to the features you allow (using `-msse2` or `-mavx` for instance).

Comment: Generally prefer `-march=haswell` or something, rather than manual `-mavx2`.  The "generic" tuning options are not great for 256-bit vectors on Intel CPUs: [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726)

Answer (score 5):

What you want are [intrinsics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function), which look like library functions but are actually built into the compiler so they translate into specific machine code.

Paul R and hroptatyr describe where to find GCC's documentation. [Microsoft also has good documentation on the intrinsics in their compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); even if you are using GCC, you might find MS' description of the idea a better tutorial.

Comment: What about ARM architecture? Does it support NEON SIMD? or this is only meant for x86?

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek Question specifies x86-64. ARM and NEON have their own compiler and own intrinsics.