# Intel SSE and AVX Examples and Tutorials

Tags: intel, sse, vectorization, avx

Is there any good C/C++ tutorials or examples for learning Intel SSE and AVX instructions?

I found few on Microsoft MSDN and Intel sites, but it would be great to understand it from the basics..

Comment: See my summary on SIMD here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933746/parallel-programming-using-haswell-architecture/20948208#20948208

Comment: There are some links in the [SSE tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).  Especially [SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015) slide](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) are nice and have some good stuff about laying out your data for SIMD.  (i.e. don't use a SIMD vector as a 3D xyz vector and then give up on SIMD because it wasn't faster.)

Comment: [Getting started with Intel x86 SSE SIMD instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1389712/995714)

Answer (score 16):

For the visually inclined SIMD programmer, Stefano Tommesani's site is the best introduction to x86 SIMD programming.

http://www.tommesani.com/index.php/simd/46-sse-arithmetic.html

The diagrams are only provided for MMX and SSE2, but once a learner gets proficient with SSE2, it is relatively easy to move on and read the formal specifications.

---

Intel IA-32 Instructions beginning with A to M

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf

Intel IA-32 Instructions beginning with N to Z

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf

---

In addition, it is important for Intel SIMD programmers to know the minimum required architecture for instructions that are outside the SSE2 generation.

Browsing by generations on Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.1#SSE4.1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.2#SSE4.2

Searching for a given Intel SIMD mnemonic on a single page (via a text search):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

---

Answer (score 4):

There is some good stuff on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com), e.g. [SSE Performance Programming](http://www.thomasdideriksen.dk/misc/SIMD/Accelerate_sse_migration.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice introduction here

[Code project SSE](http://web.archive.org/web/20150531202539/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4522/Introduction-to-SSE-Programming)

Also if you have [Microsoft DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) installed, the source from xnamath has lot of vector/matrix operations using sse intrinsics (check in the sdk include folder, xnamath.h, xnamathconvert.inl, xnamathmatrix.inl ...)

Answer (score 3):

You might find it useful to look at examples of how SIMD can be applied to some common algorithms. At Games Developer Conference 2011, there was an Intel talk called ["Hotspots, FLOPS, and uOps: To-the-Metal CPU Optimization"](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014645) that attempts to demonstrate SIMD for algorithms common in games. The talk refers to some [Intel sample code that shows how AVX can be applied to cloth calculations](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/soa-cloth-simulation-with-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx).