# can't find materials about SSE2, Altivec, VMX on apple developer

Tags: sse, avx, sse2, altivec

as Paul. R sugguested that there are plenty of resources about SSE2 , AVX on apple developer but I couldn't find it. Could anyone helps me ? 
BTW, I also looking for the archive of mail-list of altivec.

thanks!

[Intel SSE and AVX Examples and Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577226/intel-sse-and-avx-examples-and-tutorials)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/Accelerate_sse_migration/Accelerate_sse_migration.pdf

Comment: @rwong: thanks for the link - I've updated the original answer. To the OP: I still have much of the old AltiVec mailing list archived - let me know how to send it to you.

Comment: @Paul R, please send the archive to benzwt@gmail.com, thanks!

Comment: @prgbenz: OK - it's done!