# How to use x86intrin.h

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, intrinsics, bmi

In one of my applications, I need to efficiently de-interleave bits in a long stream of data.  Ideally, I would like to use the BMI2 `pext_u32()` and/or `pext_u64()` x86_64 intrinsic instructions when available.  I scoured the internet for doc on `x86intrin.h` (**GCC**), but couldn't find much on the subject; so, I am asking the gurus on StackOverflow to help me out.

1. Where can I find documentation about how to work with functions in `x86intrin.h`?
2. Does **gcc**'s implementation of `pext_*()` already have code behind it to fall back on, or do I need to write the fallback code myself (for conditional compile)?
3. Is it possible to write a binary that automatically falls back to an alternate implementation if a target does not support the intrinsic?  If so, how does one do so?
4. Is there a known programming pattern that will be recognized by **GCC** and automatically converted to `pext_*()` when compiling with optimization enabled and with `-mbmi2`?

Comment: I have posted some minimal basic hello world examples at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389712/getting-started-with-intel-x86-sse-simd-instructions/56409539#56409539

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intel publishes the [Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), which also applies to GCC.  You will have to write your own fallback code if you use these intrinsics.

You can achieve automatic switching of implementations by using [IFUNC resolvers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-ifunc-function-attribute), but for non-library code, using conditionals or function pointers is probably simpler.

Looking at the `gcc/config/i386/i386.md` and `gcc/config/i386/i386.c` files, I don't see anything in GCC 8 which would automatically select the `pext` instruction without intrinsics in the source code.

Comment: Some things like the target_clones attribute can create the ifunc resolver for you, though it may not be so convenient for this particular case.

Comment: Yes, target clones only work if the code itself is architecture-independent. This is not the case when CPU-specific intrinsics are used.

Comment: @Florian, thank you for your excellent input - and this has answered almost all of my question. Will you add to your answer if you know about any source that I could find about the opcodes that gcc supports and will attempt as an optimization target?

Comment: Well, you need to look at `i386.md` and `i366.c` for this information. There is no other neat source.

Comment: @Florian, I am actually building 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the same DLL with mingw (using `_pext*()` as an option on the 64-bit version) -- cross compiling from Linux to Windows (if that also makes a difference).  Do ifunc resolvers work on Windows DLL's (both 32-bit, and 64-bit)?

Comment: Sorry, no IFUNC resolvers are a GNU/ELF feature. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The design philosophy of Intel's intrinsics is that you can only use them in functions that will run only on CPUs with the required extensions.  Checking for support every instruction would add *way* too much overhead, and then there's have to be a fallback (there isn't).

Intel intrinsics are not like GNU C `__builtin_popcountll` (which does use a fallback if compiled without `-mpopcnt`, but not you can enable target options on a per-function basis with attributes.)