# Why is memory intensive process slowing down Windows so badly?

Tags: windows, resources, cpu-usage, lag

I have an 4-core Ivy Bridge system running Win7 x64. I run a single-thread process that makes heavy use of integer MUL and DIV and allocates a lot of memory (some GBs of 16 GB total). What's more, this process runs with a processor affinity set (because that makes it run faster).

When the process is running, the whole system is sometimes lagging for seconds (literally 5-10 secs sometimes) and I don't understand why.

- There is still 10GB RAM available, far more than is needed.
- There are still 3 unused cores, PROCEXP shows clearly they are not used.
- My number crunching process doesn't use any other resources I know of: no disk, no network, no events or the like.

I just cannot understand why my user experience is influenced so badly. That happens even if I set the process class to IDLE. What's more, how can I investigate what is slowing down Windows? Usually, I would look for high CPU load or many handles or page faults, but all that is low. My guess is that my process blocks some Windows resource, but I don't know which.

**Update**: as was explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472603/1045800, i tried "Random Pausing", but to no avail: the stack trace always starts somewhere in my code, just crunching away, no resource access with `KiApcInterrupt`. I don't see any access to a Windows resource that could be the reason for a delay.

**Update**: The process is a console app, but it very rarely makes any output.

Comment: Curious.  Does your process have a GUI at all?  I'd also suggest that you try turning off the processor affinity and see if that makes any difference.  Could be you're competing with some critical process that, for reasons of its own, is also running only on that one core.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: Have you tried splitting your app on more than one thread?

Comment: That is not possible, since said process needs all that memory and cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Does it allocate the memory in  large chunks a few times, or in small amount frequently? (The heap is protected by spin locks, if your allocation profile makes the heap manager pick an unfortunate code path, I believe this could affect system overall performance)

Comment: It allocates the memory only once and then works on it.