# How to find the wait time to service time ratio in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to calculate the maximum number of threads that can be created for a specific application based on my system configuration.

I've gone through one formula for this:

```
N_threads = N_cpu * U_cpu * (1 + W / C)

where,
    N_threads is the optimal number of threads
    N_cpu is the number of prcessors
    U_cpu is the target CPU utilization 
    W / C is the ratio of wait time to compute time (0 for CPU-bound task,   maybe 10 or 100 for slow I/O tasks)
```

Based on what W/c is calculated for I/o bound tasks.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958877/5657159, might be the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

the ratio "W / C" depend on various  parameters and can different between development environment and real service environment. IMHO, the best practice is convert #thread to parameter, and probe it with various values then choose the value that give your system the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

`W/C` represents the ratio between **the waiting time** over **the computing time** and it belongs to the range `[0; 100]`.

For example, when you choose 10 as the value of `W/C`, it means that the waiting time should be 10 times larger than the computing time. In general, the higher value, the longer waiting time is.

I have no exact method to identify this ratio. But I would share with you my heuristic one. I would ask myself: "**How likely I should wait for the answers from other hosts?**"

- most of the time: [image]
- sometimes: [image]
- there is no waiting time, then of course 0