# Task.WhenAll not faster than foreach

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a long work

```
    var works = ...
    List<FormatObject> ret = new List<FormatObject>();
    foreach (var w in works)
    {
       l.AddRange(await Info.GetInfo(w));
    }
    return Ok(ret);
```

It's took approximately 76 seconds.

I tried with parallel Task.WhenAll:

```
   var works ...
   var ret = await Task.WhenAll(works.Select(Info.GetInfo));
   return Ok(ret);
```

It's also took approximately 76 seconds. So Task.WhenAll is not faster than foreach loop. I thought Task.WhenAll does the work in parallel, so should be faster than foreach which do sequentially. What was I wrong? How can I execute my work in parallel and get the result returned in just one second?

Comment: No. [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) is not used for this purpose. You need to read about parallel processing and [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) Loop.

Comment: I tried Parallel.ForEarch, but I need return result from my work, but Parallel.ForEach return immediately with no result

Comment: also `List<T>` is not thread safe.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` doesn't *do work in parallel*, rather, it simply provides a way for you to know when all of the provided tasks have finished.  You need to provide a series of already working tasks (which may or may not be able to do their work in parallel) to it for it to do that.

Comment: @S.Akbari That's not true at all. While it's true that asynchronous work doesn't *need* to do things in parallel, it certainly *can* do things in parallel, and you certainly don't need something like `Parallel.ForEach`, which does a very specific operation, namely CPU bound work on a collection of items in which each item's value can be independantly processed.  That plausibly isn't the case here (this looks like IO bound work).

Comment: @DanielA.White The List is never manipulated from multiple threads at the same time in the original code, and the second snippet doesn't use a list.

Comment: I am guessing Info.GetInfo is [I/O bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean) like database or service call?

Comment: @MinhGiang can you repeat your test with setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to a larger value which 2 by default. (If your requests are to the same site)

Comment: @L.B I'm using asp netcore. Where can I set up ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit ?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `WhenAll` at all.  You called `Info.GetInfo` a whole bunch of times, and you called it in such a way that you started subsequent calls without requiring the earlier calls to have finished.  You then, after starting all of them, used `WhenAll` to be notified when they had all finished.

Whether the work is able to be done in parallel is entirely based on the implementation of `Info.GetInfo`.  If the internal implementation of that operation, whatever it is, cannot allow multiple invocations to do productive work in parallel (possibly by using asynchronous synchronization mechanisms) then running a whole bunch of them at once won't speed the program up.  Another possibility is that the method isn't actually asynchronous (even though it's signature indicates that it *ought* to be asynchronous) and it might not actually be returning the `Task` to you until the work is done, rather than quickly returning a `Task` and doing the work later, as it ought to do.

Comment: Info.GetInfo Call HttpRequest with await request.GetResponseAsync()

Comment: @MinhGiang - edit your question with that information. Also fix the l/ret typo.