# How to force Paralled.Invoke to wait for all tasks to complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am using `Parallel.invoke` for executing multiple tasks but it returns the response before all the operations are completed. I want to use await keyboard while calling methods as all the methods are `async` but it doesn't allow me to do so. Also I know I can use `Task.WhenAll()` but the requirement is to use `Parallel.Invoke` so is there any way to achieve my goal?

```
var list = new List<string>();
var myArr = new string[] { "usa", "eng", "fra"  };

Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{
    myArr.Select(i => {
        var data= MyMethod(i);
        list.Add(1, data);
    });
});
```

and the MyMethod implementation

```
public async Task<string> GetName(string country)
{
    var data = await _db.GetAll().FindAsync(country).Capital;
    return data;
}
```

Also I have another question is there any better approach to call  the method 3 or 4 times inside `Parallel.Invoke`?

Comment: `Parallel.Invoke()` waits for all the tasks that it spawns to complete. You must have a mistake in your code somewhere.

Comment: What are the signatures of the methods that you're calling?

Comment: Thanks for the response. let me recheck my code. Also another thing that I forgot to mention in question that I want add the response returned by async method in a list so I can do that without await keyword? – Ask just now

Comment: If those methods return a `Task` then `Parallel.Invoke` will return immediately because it doesn't care if the tasks are running or not.

Comment: method1 is basically an async method that returns a response from http request. I want to add that response in list like {var a = method1(); list.Add(a)}

Comment: Can you show the whole code? The request and everything? I think I have a solution that would encompass the entire thing that would be better than doing just this one bit.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have updated my question. Can you review?

Comment: `myArr.Select` does nothing

Comment: @Backs, you're right. Actually I was working on that part but I thought first I should fix the first issue than I'll go to the next one

Comment: @Ask - You mentioned a HTTP request, but the code doesn't show it. Your code shows a `_db` but you don't say what it is. There's a `MyMethod` call, but you don't provide details for that. We need a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I know I can use Task.WhenAll() but the requirement is to use
>   Parallel.Invoke so is there any way to achieve my goal?

Your requirement to use `Parallel.Invoke` is likely wrong.

Your `GetName` method is [IO bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean). There is very little benefit in threading this. All you're doing is spawning more threads that you then have to `await` the async result of. This is **less** efficient than just looping.

It would make more sense to run this asynchronously. That way you don't use unnecessary threads but you use your main thread more effectively. You can do this using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var myArr = new string[] { "usa", "eng", "fra"  };
IEnumerable<Task<string>> myTasks = myArr.Select(i => {
                    GetName(i);
                });

await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
foreach(Task<string> task in myTasks)
{
     string result = task.Result;
}
```

Comment: thanks, another thing I might need to add the GetName() response in dictionary instead of a list. So is this approach fine for(int i = 0 i <= myTasks.Length -1; i++) { dictionary.Add(myArr(i), myTasks[i]); } Or is there any better approach?

Comment: You'd need to process the `Dictionary` after your async calls have returned I think. But it's not clear what your asking in comments. Probably ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<string>();
var myArr = new string[] { "usa", "eng", "fra" };

var tasks = myArr.Select(o => GetName(o));

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I already had this solution but my friend was convinced to use Paraller.Invoke

Comment: @Ask using Task, async, await is more preferable way in modern C# solutions

Comment: @Ask your friend is wrong

Comment: Thanks, One last question. can I use Paraller.ForEach() here?

Comment: @Ask don't mix Parallel and Task - it's bad idea, try to use only one way

Comment: Maybe but the [semantics are tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Comment: Why does this have a `Task.Run`? `GetName` already returns a `Task`. There is no benefit in utilising another thread pool thread here.

Comment: @Liam yes, you are right about Task.Run, but return is needn't