# What's the difference between Web Workers and Worker Threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I haven't been able to find any resources that explain the difference between Web Workers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), which have been around for years and enable PWA's, and Worker Threads (https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads), which have recently been released in Node.js.

To my understanding both are simply ways of allowing JavaScript to run code in multiple threads. So why are Worker Threads being released as a "new" thing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Web Workers** are a technology that exists **in browsers**.

**Worker Threads** are a technology that exists **in node.js**.

They have similar goals, but due to environment differences, they have different implementations.

> To my understanding both are simply ways of allowing JavaScript to run code in multiple threads.

Yes, that is correct.  With significant limitations such as no access to the same variables as the main thread and in the browser, no access to the DOM.  Communication between threads and the main thread is generally done via messaging.

> So why are Worker Threads being released as a "new" thing?

Node.js has not had the ability to run Javascript code in threads until the "new" Worker Threads.  node.js never had Web Workers.  Web Workers have existed in the browser for awhile.  Before Worker Threads, developers had to use multiple processes to involve additional CPUs or to keep CPU-intensive code from blocking the event loop.  Now, node.js developers can do this with Worker Threads.

> Some of the developer discussion for why nodejs Worker Threads are different than the browser's Web Workers can be read here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43583.

Comment: Nodejs did have spawnchild/cluster.. but difference being that cluster runs on new core of cpu, whereas threads run on same core. you can multiple threads on a single cpu but ideally 1 thread per core.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - A modern operating system uses multiple cores for threads too.

Comment: Isn't a thread associated with a single core, so a thread would always remain with a core it was started in. And a single core could have N threads. And X cores could have N*X threads. Last point was that fewer threads there are per core, the better it's due to cost of "Context Switching"

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - When a thread is actually executing, it won't jump from one core to another, but if the OS time slices it out to let other threads have their fair turn, it can come back on any core unless it is bound to a specific core.  Plus threads are not bound to the core that their parent process is running on.  Keep in mind that in a modern OS, there can already lots of other threads that are part of the housekeeping of running the OS.  When I look in Process Explorer on my Windows 10 system right now, there are already hundreds of threads.

Comment: It would be good to clarify why they didn't just implement Web Workers in Node.js, rather than creating a new API, i.e. how the APIs differ.

Comment: I'm seconding the @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com 's question, with a request to elaborate the simple answer "worker threads exist on server, web workers exist in browser, that's why". Edit: found a discussion https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43583

Comment: @fedd - I added your link to my answer as a reference for some of the reasons they are different.