# how to print the time in linux

Tags: c

so I was using rusage to print out how long it takes from the user, and system to process a command, something along the lines of,

```
           //DO STUFF HERE
           printf(" TOTAL TIMES: ");
           tusage.ru_utime.tv_sec  = rusage.ru_utime.tv_sec + rusage.ru_stime.tv_sec;
```

Comment: What's the problem with using `getrusage` in linux?

Comment: use `gettimeofday`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150291/how-do-i-measure-a-time-interval-in-c)

Comment: @Art the same code prints 0.00 in linux, but same code prints actual value in mac os why is that?

Comment: @RichardMckenna, because linux is fast ;D

Comment: @RichardMckenna because your program didn't take any measurable time to run? Your exact example works for me (even if I question why you'd use a struct rusage for storage for the sum instead of just a struct timeval).

Comment: @FredrikPihl I need the amount of time it took the system to process it, the user, and thats generally given by rusage

Comment: add a big loop in your code and see if you can get a non-zero value

Comment: @perreal I just did and still got 0

Comment: @RichardMckenna Then the loop wasn't long enough or the compiler optimized it away.

Comment: @Art I just ran a disk usage du -sh \usr and it still printed 0

Comment: @RichardMckenna Ran it how?

Comment: If the same code works on a mac it should also work on linux right?

Comment: @Art look at my updated code that is what works on mac but does prints 0 for Linux ubuntu

Comment: @RichardMckenna, try the one below, does it print 0?

Comment: @perreal I updated my code please look at it.

Comment: If you ran something by either `fork`/`exec` yourself or with `system`, it will not take any time in your process. That's what `SELF` in `RUSAGE_SELF` means. If you want to measure how long time your children processes took, use `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`. At least that's what I decode from your "du -sh /usr" comment. You updated code just removed the call to `getrusage`.

Comment: where would I put the RUSAGE_CHILDREN? in the beginning?

Comment: replace the `RUSAGE_SELF` with `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`

Comment: @Art you are right, I am execing, forking, in my large program, but on a mac I get the behavior I want using netbeans. Why cant I get the same fricking output on linux when compiled with the same gcc. I don't even feel like changing my logic cause IT WORKS EXACTLY AS EXPECTED on a Mac using netbeans

Comment: It doesn't. MacOS has the exact same behavior of the `getrusage` call.  It's POSIX and it has been a standard in Unix since the middle of the 80s. Possibly MacOS has more precise timers. Possibly Linux has more optimized fork/exec so that their clock quantum can't measure it. But `getrusage` does the same thing on both systems.

Comment: @Art If my program DOES have some execs but ideally I want to calculate the TIME it took it run a command, what would I be measuring child or self? I feel like self would include child and if I do just child then I am not including the work the self did to get to the child, etc, etc.

Comment: Read the man page for `getrusage` it explains exactly what it measures. If you want the total sum of resource usage for the children of your process, `getrusage` is enough. If you want the resource usage for specific children of your process, read the man page for `wait4`. If you want the time to run a command, instead of rolling your own you can just use "time <name of your command>" in the shell.

Comment: ok so my rusage approach is good. If a command takes 0.0030 seconds on a mac on average is it okay to be 0.000 on linux?

Comment: Please take any discussion to [chat] and edit any useful information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
int main() {
  struct rusage rusage;
  struct rusage tusage;
  int i, j, r=0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < 100000; j++) {
      r = i % j + i / j;
    }
  }
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage);
  printf("TOTAL TIME \n");
  tusage.ru_utime.tv_sec =  rusage.ru_utime.tv_sec + rusage.ru_stime.tv_sec;
  tusage.ru_utime.tv_usec = rusage.ru_utime.tv_usec + rusage.ru_stime.tv_usec;
  tusage.ru_utime.tv_sec += tusage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000;
  tusage.ru_utime.tv_usec = tusage.ru_utime.tv_usec % 1000000;
  printf("%ld.%06ld\n", tusage.ru_utime.tv_sec, tusage.ru_utime.tv_usec);

  return r;
}
```

Comment: no it did not. But why does something on a mac take long yet all my realistic commands are showing up as 0.00

Comment: I don't really know, just a call to getrusage returns non-zero time for me (`0.001000`).