# How to get CPU time used by a thread given its ID?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cpu-usage, getrusage

So I want to get the cpu time used by a thread given its ID. `getrusage` is not applicable here as `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r_usage);` returns the resources used by the thread that calls it, here I want to get resources of a thread other than the one I am in.

Comment: Any reason why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150291/how-do-i-measure-a-time-interval-in-c won't work for you?

Comment: because I need CPU time not wall clock time

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?