# Measure time elapsed in C++

Tags: c++, linux, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fast elapsed time on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380136/fast-elapsed-time-on-linux)

How can I measure how long a function takes to execute in C++? It would be best if I could get the time to a fraction of a millisecond, but if not accuracy to one millisecond should be good enough. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 if that means anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <ctime>
int main(){
    clock_t start = clock();
    // your program goes here
    clock_t ends = clock();
    cout << "Time elapsed: " << (double) (ends - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very low precision approximation rather than elapsed time. Division by CLOCKS_PER_SEC also looks odd as this is a hard-coded macro that doesn't really represent a number of clocks per second. Plus, it is not a wall clock. So if you real-time process was swapped out, it will give you some totally weird results... :-]

Comment: How accurate is that going to be?

Comment: @Vlad: clock_gettime is an adequate alternative i guess..

Comment: This works for me pretty accurately, but it's definitely not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The best clock for performance measurement is system-wide real-time clock. In Linux, you can use [`clock_gettime`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) function with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`. Those will give you nanosecond precision.