# How many lines in a file with count always returns 1

Tags: php

I'm extremely new to php and I am trying to get how many lines there are in my file.  I am currently using some code I found online.

```
$file = "filename";
$lines = count(file($file));
```

This returns `1`. and there are MANY more lines than that.  Any insight? Does it have something to do with new line characters? I did a `$fh = file($file); split('\n', $fh);` and the count of that is still 1....so I am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb

Comment: What you are doing should work - what happens when you `print_r(file($file))`? How many elements does the output have? Does it contain all of your file? Also, what platform are you working on? It's not OSX by any chance is it...?

Comment: Are you sure that the file has more than one line?

Comment: Returns 0...and I think it's empty.....Also no I am not on osx. I'm on ubuntu

Comment: The file is pretty large and it definitely has more than 1 line.

Comment: Sounds like you not actually managing to open your file, are you sure the path makes sense in the context it's used in your script? Try and `print(getcwd())` and make sure your working in the directory you think you are. Also `var_dump(is_file($file))` and `var_dump(is_readable($file))` to make sure PHP can see your file, and read it - you might need to chmod it...

Comment: Thanks.  You're actually right I just fixed the issue and implemented @corum 's solution below and it works.  The issue was `$file` was being used as a global variable when it was actually a local one. Rookie mistake...kind of embarrassing.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$lines = 0;

if ($fh = fopen('file.txt', 'r')) {
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    if (fgets($fh)) {
      $lines++;
    }
  }
}
echo $lines; // line count
```