# How to get number of lines with SplFileObject?

Tags: php, spl

```
$file = new SplFileObject('/path/to/file.txt');
```

How can I find the number of lines in a file with [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use file handlers and do like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb)? Its simple, fast and very efficient.

If you absolutely must use spl, you can do it like this

```
$file = new SplFileObject("/path/to/file.txt");
$i = 0;
while (!$file->eof()) {
    $i++;
    $file->next();
}
print "file has " . $i . " lines";
```

Comment: I used fopen/fgets traditional way of reading files as you recommended, thanks. Sometimes I am just trying to do everything with classes when it's not needed.

Comment: If you want to do your filehandling in an object oriented way, thats exactly why SPL exists.

Answer (score 45):

`iterator_count` and line-by-line iterating using `next()` is broken in my php version 5.3.7 under Ubuntu.

Also seems broken `fseek([any offset], SEEK_END)` method. `key()` returns 0.

Iterate over large files using `seek($lineCount)` is too slow.

Simpliest 5.3.7-verified way is

```
// force to seek to last line, won't raise error
$file->seek($file->getSize());
$linesTotal = $file->key();
```

Counting 30000 lines requires now 0.00002 secs and costs about 20 kb of memory.

Iterations method takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: this is wrong, seek() will look for line number while getSize() will return the filesize in bytes.

Comment: I know. It just ensures that we seeked __all__ file lines (even if all of them are empty).

At most common cases, seek() will bump to EOF on line number that definitely less than bytes count, but PHP handles it silently, returning last line number.

Agree, it is dirty hack, but i didn't found any "clean" way to count lines quickly.

Comment: works fine.  But file has 99 lines but it returns 98. do you know why?

Comment: NOTE: key returns the index of the last line so this will always be one short of the total. You need to add one to the total: `$linesTotal = $file->key() + 1;`

Comment: @Simon, can you expand on your explanation of why you need add one to the total? Do you mean because the array starts with 0, you need to add 1 to the total?

Comment: @Motivated This was two years ago so I can't confirm any of this. But, yes, the `key()` function returns a 0-based index, meaning the total will always be +1.

Answer (score 18):

I agree with [Николай Конев](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665581/) on using `seek function` is much faster than going through the entire file line by line, but as [Twisted1919](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600061/twisted1919) said using the file size to seek the last line is confusing so my suggestion is use [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) instead of the file size:

```
// force to seek to last line, won't raise error
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
$linesTotal = $file->key();
```

Answer (score 6):

The `SplFileObject` offers an itertor, one iteration per line:

```
$numberOfLines = iterator_count($file);
```

The function [`iterator_count`](http://php.net/iterator_count) is your friend here, doing the traversal for you and returning the number of iterations.

You can make use of the file object's [`SKIP_EMPTY` flag](http://php.net/class.splfileobject#splfileobject.constants.skip-empty) to not count empty lines in that file.

Comment: Great answer but on larger file (10mb and 135,000+ lines in this case) it is entirely too slow and an attempt to count using this method actually results in a time out.