# Count lines of file in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, numbers, exec, lines

To determine the exact number of lines in a file I currently use:

```
if(exec("wc -l ".escapeshellarg($strFile), $arResult)) {
     $arNum = explode(" ", $arResult[0]);
     // ...
  }
```

What is the best way of doing the same on Windows?

---

**Edit:**

One attempt from another question:

```
$file="largefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

1. Has anyone got experience with this way using big files?
2. Is there a way of using **Windows commands** to determine file size other then PHP functions?

---

**Solution**

I go with command `find` as recommended by the accepted answer in the comments.

Comment: All answers so far recommend `file()`. Take into account that this function loads the entire file into memory!

Comment: might be [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb) to count lines in a file

Comment: @tradyblix - Nice catch. I was sure the question was a dupe but I couldn't find it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found an answer in your link, check the edit in my initial posting.

Comment: As noted in the answer the code comes from, you can find very large lines (e.g. binary files). Use the second snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to just loop through the file, reading a line each time and incrementing a counter, using and counting the array returned by [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) is only good for smaller files.

```
<?php

$loc = 'Ubuntu - 10.10 i386.iso';

$f = fopen($loc,'r');
$count = 0;

while (fgets($f)) $count++;

fclose($f);

print "Our file has $count lines" . PHP_EOL;
```

if you'd use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for a such a large file it would read it completely into memory, which can be prohibitive depending on your situation. If this is a 1-time "I don't care, it's my workstation and I have enough memory" situation or the files are guaranteed to be small then you could use

```
count(file($loc));
```

Otherwise I'd loop through, especially since if action would have to be performed by many processes. Both ways of counting loop through the whole of the file but memory increases vastly in the second case.

Comment: you realize you could just keep using wc -l via cygwin right? :)

Comment: I do not have control over server environment.

Comment: could you run a batch script /DOS command via shell_exec/exec? like `find /V /C "&!@Not_Existing&!@" my_file.text` the chance that that string is in a file of yours should be small :)

Comment: Thanks! My code: `if(exec('find /V /C "&!@Not_Existing&!@" '. escapeshellarg($strFile), $arResult)) {
            $arResult[0];
         } else { // ... try fopen() }` I have no clue what `find` returns! Is the line number `$arResult` or `$arResult[0]`? Got no Windows here.

Comment: me neither but it seems to be the 2nd parameter (http://www.robvanderwoude.com/find.php ) just do a print_r and find out. :)

Comment: Im gonna accept your answer since you were the first coming up with `find`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use:

```
$length = count(file($filename));
```

Which would work everywhere.

`file()` reads the file into an array, split on newlines, and `count()` counts the length of an array.

If it doesn't work properly (at macintosh files for example), take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

Comment: should work but take note it loads the file into memory which is not good for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Windows command to calculate line numbers:

```
find /c /v "" < type file-name.txt
```

Adapted from [Stupid command-line trick: Counting the number of lines in stdin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/25/10200026.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is using `substr_count` and is much faster than `fgets`:

```
$file="largefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$chunk_size = (2<<20); // 2MB chuncks

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($handle)){
    $chunk = fread($handle,$chunk_size);
    $linecount += substr_count($chunk,PHP_EOL);
    // $linecount += substr_count($chunk,"\n"); // also with \n, \r, or \r\n
}
fclose($handle);
echo $linecount;
```

The code is taking into consideration the use of least memory (2 MB chunks).
*Benchmark* with a 85 MB file and 8M+ lines, execution time is:
• `fgets`: 52.11271 sec.
• `substr_count(PHP_EOL)`: 0.58844 sec.
• `substr_count(\n)`: 0.353772 sec.
• `find /c /v "" largefile.txt`: 100 sec.

However, if one have no problem with the memory available on the host system, like the OP, and proper memory limit in PHP is set (larger than the file length), `substr_count` can search the entire content of file with much performance:

```
$file="largefile.txt";
@ini_set('memory_limit', (2<<24)+(filesize($file)) ); // 32 MB for PHP + File size
$linecount = 0;
$handle = file_get_contents($file);
if($handle) $linecount = substr_count($handle, PHP_EOL);
echo $linecount;
```

You may choose whatever memory size you want for the interpreter.
*Benchmark*: **0.46878** sec.