# PHP: How to get random line in big file fastest?

Tags: php, performance, line

I have 1 file txt with 100 000 lines. Can you know any way to get 1 line fastest randomly ? Thank you very much !

Comment: why don't you benchmark some ideas you have.. `$line = file($filename)[rand(0,100000)];` could be one test you run

Comment: Your going to have to loop though it to find the number of lines. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537130/1281385

Comment: DannyHearnah's suggestion will be faster, but use more memory. exussums will use almost no memory, but will be slower.

Comment: Depends on the desired per-line randomness. A trivial abstraction would be to just [`fseek`](http://php.net/fseek) to an arbitrary *byte* position, read a sufficiently large windoe (8K ?) then find the nearest linebreak, and extract between that and the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be to build index (simple array that contains the position in the file of each new line). Then choose random key, get the position, fseek the file to that position, and read the line. This will require updating the index file any time you change the file, but if you want to optimize retrieving the data, that's the way.

You can optimize further by spliting the file in ranges (e.g. sharding the data), or having several representations of the file (for example you can have file with lines inverted so last come first, and if your random number is bigger than half of the elements, you read from the second file)