# Pass stream by reference

Tags: c, pointers, stream, pass-by-reference, pointer-to-pointer

I am suppose to pass stream, which is a pointer, by reference. So I am passing this as a pointer to a pointer. Can someone please verify my code?

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *stream;

    printf("LINES: %d\n",scan(stream));
}

int scan(FILE *(*stream))
{
    stream = fopen("names.txt", "r");

    int ch = 0, lines=0;

    while (!feof(*stream))
    {
        ch = fgetc(*stream);
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(*stream);
    return lines;
}
```

No output received.

Comment: [while-feof-file-is-always-wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3386109)

Comment: _Can someone please verify my code?_ The compiler will verify your code.

Comment: @user3386109 It's not wrong. I have test and it works.

Comment: @MOehm I did compile and thus I stated _No output received_. I am learning.

Comment: Appears to work it does, but not for the reasons you believe. There's a difference between code that is correct, and code that works for the wrong reasons.  `while ( (ch = fgetc(*stream)) != EOF )` is the correct way to write that `while` loop.

Comment: @user3386109 As i mentioned I am learning, I picked up this format from the answer given by _Dominic Rodger_ on page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb)

Comment: Ahh, but notice all of the dollar signs in the code. That's not C code, it's PHP. Check the tags in the question.

Comment: @user3386109 I will try to be more careful. Can you help me in another question please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823218/rewind-a-text-file-and-populate-dynamic-array-stream-passed-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
stream = fopen("names.txt", "r");
```

with

```
*stream = fopen("names.txt", "r");
```

Also

```
printf("LINES: %d\n",scan(stream));
```

with

```
printf("LINES: %d\n",scan(&stream));
```

Comment: @user3386109 would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @Vagish Also, can you explain how can I pass stream by value?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
int scan(FILE **stream) //no need for brackets
{
    *stream = fopen("names.txt", "r"); //* is for dereferencing

    if(*stream==NULL) // Checking the return value of fopen
    {
        printf("An error occured when opening 'names.txt'");
        return -1;
    }

    int ch = 0, lines=0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(*stream))!=EOF) //while(!feof) is wrong
    {

        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(*stream); // Close the FILE stream after use
    return lines;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *stream;

    printf("LINES: %d\n",scan(&stream)); //Pass address of `stream`. The address is of type `FILE**`
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what good is it to pass a pointer to file handle if you don't use the created handle outside the function? You (and the OP) should also `fclose´ the file.

Comment: `while ( (ch = fgetc(*stream)) != EOF )`

Comment: @MOehm ,Maybe the OP has some requirement. And thanks for reminding me about the `fclose`. I've added it.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yes, of course, there might be a special requirement that we don't know of. Now that the OP has inserted `fclose` it is clear that there is simply a misconception of what passing pointers to stuff from outside is for. Your answer answers the question, but in my opinion, the question was a bit wrong-headed in the first place. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has design issues. What exactly do you want to achieve?

If you just want to count the lines, make the `FILE *` local to your function:

```
int count_lines(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");

    int lines = 0;

    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(stream);

        if (c == EOF) break;
        if (c == '\n') lines++;
    }
    fclose(stream);

    return lines;
}
```

If you want to do a regular file operation (read, write, seek, rewind etc.) to a file that has already been opened with `fopen`, just pass the handle as `FILE *`:

```
int fget_non_space(FILE *stream)
{
    int c;

    do {
        c = fgetc(stream);
    } while (isspace(c));

    return c;
}
```

In that case, both `fopen` and `fclose` are called outside this function. (You don't call `fclose` in your program, which you should, even if the operating system makes sure to close the file automatically after exiting.)

Passing a pointer to the file handle, `FILE **`, makes sense only if you want to change that file handle itself in the function, for example by calling `fopen`:

```
int fopen_to_read(FILE **FILE pstream, const char *fn) 
{
    *pstream = fopen(fn, "r");
    return (*pstream != NULL) ? 0 : -1;        
}
```

Even then, it would be better to return the file handle, as `fopen` does.

Your example code leaves the open filehandle accessible in `main`, but you don't do anything with it, you don't even close it. Is that what you want? I doubt it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It has helped me understand the whole logic/concept. But simply, I wanted to pass 'stream' by reference. I did forget to close the file (apology), I have corrected the original code in the question.

Comment: Yes, but you are aware that in your example, there isn't any point in passing the file pointer, because it is never used outside `scan`. That design is even dangerous, because before calling `scan`, `stream` is uninitialised and after callig `scan`, it refers to a close file. Still, you _can_ access `stream` in both cases, where it is invalid. The proper design would be to "encapsulate" the file handle and restrict its scope to its use.

Comment: I will try to learn better. It has been difficult for me to learn C, But I am trying to understand. Can you assist me on another problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823218/load-text-file-in-struct)