# Rewind File, Create Dynamic Struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, stream, pass-by-value

this function will rewind file, create the dynamic array (of size), and read in the data, populating the _data struct dynamic array. Note that stream 
is passed by value this time. The function then returns the populated 
array of struct

```
struct _data
{
    char* name;
    long number;
};

struct _data *load(FILE *stream, int size)
{
    struct _data BlackBox = calloc(size, sizeof(_data));

    char tempName[3];

    stream = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        fscanf(stream, "%s %ld", tempName, &data.number);
        BlackBox[i].name = calloc(strlen(tempName), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(BlackBox[i].name, tempName);
    }
    fclose(stream);

    return &BlackBox;
}

File Content
ron 7774013
jon 7774014
```

I am a beginner and having difficulty designing the code. Can someone please explain. Thanks

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @QmickZh  
Code does not compile. I want to load the content of the file to the struct. The function (*load) will be called by main.

Comment: All errors of this code can be found easily in the compiler output . You should read it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some warning from gcc to help you.

Fix memory management with your calloc, and don't return a stack pointer

```
typedef struct _data                                                           
{                                                                              
    char* name;                                                                
    long number;                                                               
} _data;                                                                       

_data *load(FILE *stream, int size)                                            
{                                                                              
    _data *BlackBox = calloc(size, sizeof(_data));                             

    char tempName[3];                                                          

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)                                                 
    {                                                                          
        fscanf(stream, "%s %ld", tempName, &BlackBox[i].number);               
        BlackBox[i].name = strdup(tempName);                                   
    }                                                                          
    fclose(stream);                                                            

    return BlackBox;                                                           
}                                                                              

int main (void)                                                                
{                                                                              
    FILE *f = fopen("test.data", "r");                                         
    _data *data = load(f, 2);                                                  
    printf("%s %ld\n", data[0].name, data[0].number);                          
    printf("%s %ld\n", data[1].name, data[1].number);                          
    return 0;                                                                  
}
```

output

```
 aurel@vm-pontarlier:~$ ./a.out 
ron 7774013
jon 7774014
```

Think about change _data

```
typedef struct _data{
    char name[256];
    long number;
} _data;
```

scan will be:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)                                                 
{                                                                          
    fscanf(stream, "%s %ld", BlackBox[i].name, &BlackBox[i].number);       
}
```

Comment: I have got multiple error's after using your program. How can I post them here?

Comment: `main.c:70:26: error: array type 'char [256]' is not assignable
        BlackBox[i].name = strdup(tempName);                                   
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^`

Comment: Use only the first part, you have mixed my first and second proposition

Comment: Second proposition is http://pastebin.com/m3R9Kh28 you can use pastebin to share error

Comment: you scan twice the file without rewind. add a rewind before call load

Answer (score 0):

You are making the same arrors as with your previous post. You also don't allocate memory for the `name` member in `_data`. As for the compilation errors:

- Arrays of type `T` that you allocate dynamically with `malloc` or `calloc` are controlled by a handle, a pointer to `T` of type `T*`.
- The structure you defined is of type `struct _data`, the type includes the keyword `struct`. If you want a one-word identifier for your type, use `typedef´ as Ôrel has shown you.
- You have no variable called ´data`. The handle to the newly allocated memory is ´BlackBox`.

If you fix these errors, you will run into logical errors that the compiler cannot know about:

- Your `BlackBox[i].name` is initialised to `NULL` via `calloc`, so it doesn't point to valid memory. You cannot `strcpy` anything into it. What you can do is to use the non-standard, but widely available `strdup`, which first allocates memory as required and then copies.
- Your temporary string is of length 3; it can hold at most two characters plus the null terminator. The names in your file are short, granted, but your program must prepare for any input, even illegal input.
- The `FILE *` isn't used outside your function; it should be local to `load`.
- The user must specify how many items to read. This defies the purpose of dynamic allocation. Also the user can't know how many items were read; there might be fewer items in the file as requested. Your function design should reflect that. (Okay, thst's not really true: You zero-initialise the memory, which means a char pointer of `NULL` signals the end of the array, but:)
- You don't test the output of `fscanf`, which you should. If your file has fewer than `size` items, the last items will contain garbage, because you copy garbage values into the zero initialised memory.
- Not an error per se, but if your file is organised along lines, consider reading a line with `fgets` first and then parsing that with `sscanf`.

The example code below tries to incorporate these guidelines. Things to note:

- The memory isn't allocated in one huge chunk, but it grows as needed with subsequent calls to `realloc`. The call `realloc(NULL, s)` is equivalent to `malloc(s)`.
- The functions "fills in"  the number of elementsread via a pointer to an integer.
- The strings are copied into newly allocated memory. That means that in theory, the strings can e as long as they want. (In practice, the max buffer length of 20 cuts such strings short.) The function `duplicate` emulates the function `strdup`.
- These strings should be `free`d when cleaning up.
- The `load` function takes a filename istead of a file handle.
- File reading takes place in two stages: Read a line first, then scan this line. If the format is not "string without spaces" + "number", an error message is written.

Anyway, here goes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _data
{
    char *name;
    long number;
};

/*
 *      Duplicate a string on the heap (aka strdup)
 */
char *duplicate(const char *str)
{
    char *p = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    strcpy(p, str);
    return p;
}

/*
 *      Read a list of names from file fn
 */
struct _data *load(const char *fn, int *psize)
{
    struct _data *data = NULL;
    FILE *stream;
    char line[80];      // buffer for line
    int lnr = 0;        // line number for error message
    int n = 0;          // number of read items

    stream = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    if (stream == NULL) return NULL;    // Can't open file

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stream)) {
        long int number;
        char buf[20];

        lnr++;
        if (sscanf(line, "%19s %ld", buf, &number) == 2) {
            data = realloc(data, (n + 1) * sizeof(*data));
            data[n].number = number;
            data[n].name = duplicate(buf);
            n++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "[%s, line %d] Illegal format\n", fn, lnr);
        }
    }
    fclose(stream);
    *psize = n;             // Assign number of read items

    return data;
}

/*
 *      Free memory allocated by load
 */
void cleanup(struct _data *data, int n)
{
    while (n--) free(data[n].name);
    free(data);
}

int main()
{
    struct _data *data;
    int i, n;

    data = load("names.txt", &n);
    if (data == NULL) return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%-20s%12ld\n", data[i].name, data[i].number);
    }

    cleanup(data, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will remember. I am good with Ruby & Java, But C is just something new to me. I apologize and I much appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Ruby and Java and most modern languages take care of memory allocation ad garbage collection for you. In C, you must take care of all that yourself. This can lead to optimised designs, but it also means that you shoot yourself in the foot very often, especially when you are still learning. Take the advice above with a grain of salt. The comments and example code are meant to be helpful, not offensive.

Comment: I take every advice and I don't find them offensive. For me it is always the learning moment and I will learn by it. I am assuming, can you advice me a good book to start understanding C. I am aware of garbage collection in Ruby and Java. C has really got my going. :(

Answer (score 0):

...and lastly tempName[3] is too small: it must be at least 4, given your 3 letter inputs. Further, you forget to allocate room for the terminating null character in your malloc call:

```
char tempName[4];
...
BlackBox[i].name = malloc(strlen(tempName)+1);
```

(That tempName[3] did not lead to errors is because the compiler probably rounded it up to an even number of bytes - but it is a typical beginner's fault.)