# How to process CSV with 100k+ lines in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file with more than 100.000 lines, each line has 3 values separated by semicolon. Total filesize is approx. 5MB.

**CSV file is in this format:**

```
stock_id;product_id;amount
==========================
1;1234;0
1;1235;1
1;1236;0
...
2;1234;3
2;1235;2
2;1236;13
...
3;1234;0
3;1235;2
3;1236;0
...
```

We have 10 stocks which are indexed 1-10 in CSV. In database we have them saved as 22-31.

CSV is sorted by stock_id, product_id but I think it doesn't matter.

**What I have**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once ('db.php');

echo '<meta charset="iso-8859-2">';

// convert table: `CSV stock id => DB stock id`
$stocks = array(
    1  => 22,
    2  => 23,
    3  => 24,
    4  => 25,
    5  => 26,
    6  => 27,
    7  => 28,
    8  => 29,
    9  => 30,
    10 => 31
);

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE fielddef_id = 1");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[$row['product_id']] = 1;
}

$csv = file('export.csv');

// go thru CSV file and prepare SQL UPDATE query
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $data = explode(';', $row);
    // $data[0] - stock_id
    // $data[1] - product_id
    // $data[2] - amount

    if (isset($products[$data[1]])) {
        // in CSV are products which aren't in database
        // there is echo which should show me queries
        echo "  UPDATE t 
                SET value = " . (int)$data[2] . " 
                WHERE   fielddef_id = " . (int)$stocks[$data[0]] . " AND 
                        product_id = '" . $data[1] . "' -- product_id isn't just numeric
                LIMIT 1<br>";
    }
}
```

Problem is that writing down 100k lines by `echo` is soooo slow, takes long minutes. I'm not sure what MySQL will do, if it will be faster, or take ± the same time. I have no testing machine here, so I'm worry about testing in on prod server.

My idea was to load CSV file into more variables (better array) like below, but I don't know why.

```
$csv[0] = lines 0      - 10.000;
$csv[1] = lines 10.001 - 20.000;
$csv[2] = lines 20.001 - 30.000;
$csv[3] = lines 30.001 - 40.000;
etc.
```

I found eg. [Efficiently counting the number of lines of a text file. (200mb+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb), but I'm not sure how it can help me.

When I replace `foreach` for `print_r`, I get dump in < 1 sec. The task is to make the foreach loop with database update faster.

Any ideas how to updates so many records in database?
Thanks.

Comment: as an alternative, you could create a file instead, then use `load data local infile` thats going to be much faster than doing all the load in PHP

Comment: Why are you using sessions? use an array store outside of the loops rather than resetting each time, it sounds like you have a fixed map between 1-10 and 21-31 so you can replace all the array look ups with simple case statements (or if's if so inclined) much faster then read your csv in with fgetcsv() loop and insert as required.  You seem to have written an awful lot of code for something you can probably do in less than 5 lines oO

Comment: @Dave: really 5 lines? Maybe possible, I'm not a programmer and do my best. Can you tell me more in asnwer? Sessions I used for loading csv file just once, but it's true the script will be launched just once. Going to remove sessions.

Comment: As a side comment: $_SESSION['products'][$row['value']] = 1; won't work because $row['value'] is always empty. You should use $row['product_id'] instead.

Comment: @EdsonMedina: just typo, sorry for that. The session was filled by product_ids correctly.

Comment: I removed sessions due to @Dave comment.

Comment: Compare it to `fgetcsv`. Maybe it will be faster than traversing the whole huge array.

Comment: You should use `SplFileObject::fgetcsv()` instead of loading the entire file in as one array. And for mysqli you should be using a prepared statement, as this will reduce performance cost dramatically when querying via a loop, as well as avoiding the "build one huge update query" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to answers and comments for the question, I have the solution. The base for that is from @Dave, I've only updated it to pass better to question.

```
<?php

require_once 'include.php';

// stock convert table (key is ID in CSV, value ID in database)
$stocks = array(
    1  => 22,
    2  => 23,
    3  => 24,
    4  => 25,
    5  => 26,
    6  => 27,
    7  => 28,
    8  => 29,
    9  => 30,
    10 => 31
);

// product IDs in CSV (value) and Database (product_id) are different. We need to take both IDs from database and create an array of e-shop products
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, value FROM cms_module_products_fieldvals WHERE fielddef_id = 1") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $products[$row['value']] = $row['product_id'];
}

$handle = fopen('import.csv', 'r');
$i = 1;

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
    $p_id = (int)$products[$data[1]];

    if ($p_id > 0) {
        // if product exists in database, continue. Without this condition it works but we do many invalid queries to database (... WHERE product_id = 0 updates nothing, but take a time)
        if ($i % 300 === 0) {
            // optional, we'll see what it do with the real traffic
            sleep(1);
        }

        $updatesql = "UPDATE table SET value = " . (int)$data[2] . " WHERE fielddef_id = " . $stocks[$data[0]] . " AND product_id = " . (int)$p_id . " LIMIT 1";
        echo "$updatesql<br>";//for debug only comment out on live
        $i++;
    }
}

// cca 1.5sec to import 100.000k+ records
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (please note this is 100% untested and off top of my head may need some tweaking to actually work :) )

```
//define array may (probably better ways of doing this
$stocks = array(
    1  => 22,
    2  => 23,
    3  => 24,
    4  => 25,
    5  => 26,
    6  => 27,
    7  => 28,
    8  => 29,
    9  => 30,
    10 => 31
);

$handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")); //open file
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    //loop through csv

    $updatesql = "UPDATE t SET `value` = ".$data[2]." WHERE   fielddef_id = ".$stocks[$data[0]]." AND product_id = ".$data[1];
   echo "$updatesql<br>";//for debug only comment out on live
}
```

There is no need to do your initial select since you're only ever setting your product data to 1 anyway in your code and it looks from your description that your product id's are always correct its just your fielddef column which has the map.

Also just for live don't forget to put your actual mysqli execute command in on your $updatesql;

To give you a comparison to actual usage code (I can benchmark against!)
This is some code I use for an importer of an uploaded file (its not perfect but it does its job)

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="beginimport") {
            echo "<h4>Starting Import</h4><br />";
            // Ignore user abort and expand time limit 
            //ignore_user_abort(true);
            set_time_limit(60);
                if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['clientimport']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    $row = 0;
                    //defaults 
                    $sitetype = 3;
                    $sitestatus = 1;
                    $startdate = "2013-01-01 00:00:00";
                    $enddate = "2013-12-31 23:59:59";
                    $createdby = 1;
                    //loop and insert
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {  // loop through each line of CSV. Returns array of that line each time so we can hard reference it if we want.
                        if ($row>0) {
                            if (strlen($data[1])>0) {
                                $clientshortcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,trim(stripslashes($data[0])));
                                $sitename = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,trim(stripslashes($data[0]))." ".trim(stripslashes($data[1])));
                                $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,trim(stripslashes($data[1])).",".trim(stripslashes($data[2])).",".trim(stripslashes($data[3])));
                                $postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,trim(stripslashes($data[4])));
                                //look up client ID
                                $client = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT ID FROM tblclients WHERE ShortCode='$clientshortcode'",ENABLE_DEBUG);

                                if ($client->ID>0 && is_numeric($client->ID)) {
                                    //got client ID so now check if site already exists we can trust the site name here since we only care about double matching against already imported sites.
                                    $sitecount = $db->countOf("tblsites","SiteName='$sitename'");
                                    if ($sitecount>0) {
                                        //site exists
                                        echo "<strong style=\"color:orange;\">SITE $sitename ALREADY EXISTS SKIPPING</strong><br />";
                                    } else {
                                        //site doesn't exist so do import
                                        $db->execute("INSERT INTO tblsites (SiteName,SiteAddress,SitePostcode,SiteType,SiteStatus,CreatedBy,StartDate,EndDate,CompanyID) VALUES 
                                        ('$sitename','$address','$postcode',$sitetype,$sitestatus,$createdby,'$startdate','$enddate',".$client->ID.")",ENABLE_DEBUG);
                                        echo "IMPORTED - ".$data[0]." - ".$data[1]."<br />";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo "<strong style=\"color:red;\">CLIENT $clientshortcode NOT FOUND PLEASE ENTER AND RE-IMPORT</strong><br />";
                                }
                                fcflush();
                                set_time_limit(60); // reset timer on loop
                            }
                        } else {
                            $row++;
                        }
                    } 
                    echo "<br />COMPLETED<br />";
                }
                fclose($handle);
                unlink($_FILES['clientimport']['tmp_name']);
            echo "All Imports finished do not reload this page";
        }
```

That imported 150k rows in about 10 seconds

Comment: I need to take all products from database; in CSV are products which aren't in database.

Comment: change the query to an insert then and use the on duplicate key update so it'll either insert a new product or update an existing. assuming that your product id's are unique keyed columns

Comment: product ids are unique, of course. But I want just to update existing ones, no insert others (in database there are only products available in e-shop, in CSV there are all product in 'normal' shop).

Comment: in which case a standard update will work fine it'll update if it exists or fail if it doesn't exist just trap the error and continue rather than die on fail.  or you can use an exists so the query won't fail horribly I'm not sure on mysqli prepared statements but they may complete anyway even if the where clause isn't matched as long as the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comment, use SPLFileObject to iterate over the CSV file. Use Prepared statements to reduce performance overhead of calling the UPDATE in each loop. Also, merge your two queries together, there isn't any reason to pull all of the product rows first and check them against the CSV. You can use a JOIN to ensure that only those stocks in the second table that are related to the product in the first and  that is the current CSV row will get updated:

```
/* First the CSV is pulled in */
$export_csv = new SplFileObject('export.csv');
$export_csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
$export_csv->setCsvControl(';');

/* Next you prepare your statement object */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
UPDATE stocks, products 
SET value = ?
WHERE
stocks.fielddef_id = ? AND 
product_id = ? AND
products.fielddef_id = 1
LIMIT 1
");

$stmt->bind_param('iis', $amount, $fielddef_id, $product_id);

/* Now you can loop through the CSV and set the fields to match the integers bound to the prepared statement and execute the update on each loop. */

foreach ($export_csv as $csv_row) {
    list($stock_id, $product_id, $amount) = $csv_row;
    $fielddef_id = $stock_id + 21;

    if(!empty($stock_id)) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the query bigger, i.e. use the loop to compile a larger query. You may need to split it up into chunks (e.g. process 100 at a time), but certainly don't do one query at a time (applies for any kind, insert, update, even select if possible). This should greatly increase the performance.

It's generally recommended that you don't query in a loop.

Comment: The same does apply, but I shall update the answer to say update :)

Comment: He's not querying in a loop. He's just echoing the SQL.

Comment: @EdsonMedina: echo just for a test, then I just wanted to replace `echo` for `mysql_query`.

Comment: @panther Is the idea replacing every record everytime?

Comment: @EdsonMedina: yes, each product in each stock will be updated (I expect only ± 1% products stays with the same amount, the rest will be changed).

Answer (score 0):

Updating every record every time will be too expensive (mostly due to seeks, but also from writing).

You should `TRUNCATE` the table first and then insert all the records again (assuming you won't have external foreign keys linking to this table).

To make it even faster, you should lock the table before the insert and unlock it afterwards. This will prevent the indexing from happening at every insert.