# how to count number of lines in a php file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to count number of files in a php file. I am using CodeIgniter framework. 
Currently I have tried this below

```
$file='contractor.php';
$mypath= 'application/controller/'.$file;
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($mypath, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $linecount++;
}
fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

Currently after executing the file in a function it keeps loading. i want to find number of lines in the file.like
output: 202

Comment: Looks as though you are missing a close `}` for the `while(!feof($handle)){`

Comment: i had missed it while writing here. with close bracket also, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one hope this will work for you :)**

```
$file = 'getinvoice'; 
no_of_lines = count(file($file)); 
echo "number of lines $file";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.

I suppose that the function keeps loading because the file is too big.

Check this answer for an efficient approach to the problem: 
[Efficiently counting the number of lines of a text file. (200mb+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 
$no_of_lines = count(file($file));
 
echo "There are $no_of_lines lines in $file"."\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

If your files are quite small, you could try something like this.

```
$lines=file($filename);
$count=count($lines);
```