# How can I redirect the output of the "time" command?

Tags: shell, unix, time, io-redirection

I tried to redirect the output of the time command, but I couldn't:

```
$time ls > filename
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

In the file I can see the output of the `ls` command, not that of `time`.
Please explain, why I couldn't and how to do this.

Comment: Should be on Superuser, I think.

Comment: The answer to this question not only of interest for programmers, but also for other power-users: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to redirect time output to file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

you can redirect the time output using,

```
(time ls) &> file
```

Because you need to take (time ls) as a single command so you can use braces.

Comment: yeah relly fine , but the question is how they did this ?

Comment: time command will take the arguments as a command. But parenthesis will group that as a one command. 
Ex:
time ls > file1.txt

In arguments,
   0  = time
   1  = "ls > file1.txt"

Comment: And time command prints the output in stderr. So you can use
(time ls) 2> file

Comment: Clarification on the `&>` please, where can I learn about these?

Comment: @hello_there_andy `&>file` is analogous to `>file 2>&1`.  It directs both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @hello_there_andy: [This page](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) has some great information on I/O redirection in BASH. It should help you to understand `&>` as well as other syntax.

Answer (score 152):

no need to launch sub shell. Use a code block will do as well.

```
{ time ls; } 2> out.txt
```

or

```
{ time ls > /dev/null 2>&1 ; } 2> out.txt
```

Comment: Agreed, Best answer.  Gives you the option to ditch the ls results and just get the time.  Thank you ghostdog74

Comment: This worked with AIX when nothing could redirect the output of the "hostent" command. Thank you!

Comment: Clarification on the `2>` please. Where can I learn about these?

Comment: how do I do it if I want both > and 2> at the same time?

Comment: how does this work? why is a subshell or block needed here?

Comment: Looks like you can capture both stdout and stderr with such as `{ time ls; } >out.txt 2>&1` . I'm guessing that time is a builtin that writes to stderr regardless of redirections placed on the same line.

Answer (score 37):

The command time sends it's output to STDERR (instead of STDOUT). That's because the command executed with time normally (in this case ls) outputs to STDOUT.

If you want to capture the output of time, then type:

```
(time ls) 2> filename
```

That captures only the output of time, but the output of ls goes normal to the console. If you want to capture both in one file, type:

```
(time ls) &> filename
```

2> redirects STDERR, &> redirects both.

Comment: This answer actually answers *why* the OP's redirect wasn't working, which was one of the questions the OP was asking.  Nobody else addresses this.

Comment: how would one pipe to another process with this?

Answer (score 11):

time is shell builtin and I'm not sure if there is way to redirect it. However you can use 
`/usr/bin/time` instead, which definitely accept any output redirections.

Comment: /usr/bin/time --output filename ls

Comment: The builtin time works well with output-redirection. It only outputs on STDERR, not on STDOUT.

Comment: The problem is that builtin commands are executed within the shell environment itself, not a subshell.  Since the stderr of your shell is typically connected to the terminal, redirection won't do anything.  To redirect the builtin time, I believe you'd have to do something like `bash time mycmd 2>file`.  Or just call `/usr/bin/time` as was mentioned.

Comment: You can also use the non-built-in without specifying the full path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540540/how-do-i-prevent-bash-to-use-a-builtin-command

Answer (score 10):

The reason why redirection does not seem to work with `time` is that it's a bash reserved word (not a builtin!) when used in front of a pipeline. bash(1):

> If the time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as
>   user and system time consumed by its execution are reported when the
>   pipeline  terminates.

So, to redirect output of `time`, either use curly braces:

```
{ time ls; } 2> filename
```

Or call `/usr/bin/time`:

```
/usr/bin/time ls 2> filename
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to mix output from `time` and the command.
With GNU time, you can use `-o file` like:

```
/usr/bin/time -o tim grep -e k /tmp 1>out 2>err
```

while `tim` is output of time, `out` and `err` are stdout and stderr from `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

I use the redirection of stdout and stderr method with braces for testing.
The `&>>rpt` represents this `>>rpt 2>&1` but shorter.
The braces will execute a command(s) in the current shell.   See: man bash

```
{ time ls a*; } &>>rpt
```

Comment: only works for bash.

Answer (score 1):

Not the canonical use case, but another way to go.

Longer running simple tasks can be launched in a detached "screen" terminal with logged output. You could even give the log a unique name.

Primarily this method is good for something that will take hours and is invoked over SSH with a need to "check up on" from time to time. In preference to backgrounding and disowning.

```
screen -dmL time -v ./crackpassword
```

You get the same output a terminal would get, with the caveat that this is asynchronous. Of course it could be a script. The output may need tweaking.