# Is there a way to pipe output of time command into a log file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I want to pipe the output of `time` command rather than the output of the job it is measuring the time of. I tried

```
 /usr/bin/time -v java RandomTest > time.log
```

But that redirects `java RandomTest`'s output to time.log

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can't I redirect the output of time command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408981/how-cant-i-redirect-the-output-of-time-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on recent Linux distributions, the time command supports the `-o FILE` option:

```
/usr/bin/time -v -o time.log java RandomTest
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is a bit tricky, but you can do it as follows:

```
{ time java RandomTest ; } 2> time.log
```

This way the result of time goes into `time.log`, and `stdout` from `java RandomTest` stays in your `tty`.

Try it first with:

```
{ time ls ; } 2> tmp.txt 

cat tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect also the stderr e.g. with `>&` in `bash` or `zsh`

(the `>&` is the same as `2>&1` since its redirects stderr to stdout)

Comment: Ah I suspected time might be writing to stderr and tried `time -v java RandomTest 2 > time.log` with no avail. I'm not familiar with the `>&` construct. How is `>& time.log` different from `2 > time.log`?

Comment: @fo_x86 :  Not sure if you have a typo there, but its `2> time.log` (not space). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes it was a careless typo.