# How is the stdout and stderr redirected here

Tags: bash, time, io-redirection

I have this:

```
$ time 2>&1 sh 2>&1 -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync" > file
```

125+0 records in

125+0 records out

64000 bytes (64 kB) copied, 0.000617678 s, 104 MB/s

real    0m0.133s

user    0m0.000s

sys 0m0.020s

```
$ cat file
```

file is empty.

Question: I understand both `dd` and `time` are sending their o/p to stderr. But since I redirected stderr to stdout for `time` and `sh` (which is the parent process of `dd`) and also sent stdout to go to file I expect things to be written to file. Why did that not happen?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408981/how-cant-i-redirect-the-output-of-time-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, with some exceptions, redirections generally occur at the point they are written.  They are removed from the command-and-argument sequence; only the remaining, non-redirection, words participate.  Thus:

```
3>&1 foo 1>&2 arg1 2>&3 arg2 3>&- arg3
```

runs `foo arg1 arg2 arg3` with stdout and stderr swapped, because:

1. `3>&1` makes a copy (more precisely, a `dup2`) of fd 1 (stdout) on fd 3
2. `1>&2` makes a copy of fd 2 (stderr) on fd 1 (so now stdout and stderr both go wherever they were going)
3. `2>&3` makes a copy of fd 3 (saved original stdout) on fd 2 (stderr)
4. `3>&-` closes fd 3.

(The notable exception is that piped output "happens first", even though the pipe symbol is at the end of the simple-command part.)

Second, as pje noted, `time` is a bash built-in.  `time foo` runs the command, then prints the time summary to bash's stderr.  The `time` keyword is effectively removed first, then the remaining command sequence is handled as usual.  (This applies even if the command is a pipeline: `time` times the entire pipeline.)

In this case, the command sequence is one simple command, with redirections:

```
2>&1 sh 2>&1 -c ... > file
```

Each redirection happens at the point it is written, and the remaining sequence is:

```
sh -c ...
```

The redirections are:

1. send stderr to wherever stdout is currently going
2. send stderr to stdout, again (this has no new effect)
3. send stdout to `file`.

so `sh -c` is run with its stderr going to your stdout, and its stdout going to file `file`.  As you note, `dd` prints its output to (its) stderr, which is `sh -c ...`'s stderr, which is your stdout.

If you run:

```
time 2>file dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125
```

you will get `time`'s stderr output on your stderr (e.g., screen), and `dd`'s stderr on file `file`.  (This happens no matter how far right you slide the `2>file` part, as long as it remains part of the simple-command.)

If you try:

```
2>file time ...
```

you will find `time`'s output redirected, but this defeats the built-in `time` entirely, running `/usr/bin/time` instead.  To get bash's built-in to fire, `time` has to be up front.  You can make a sub-shell:

```
(time ...) 2>file
```

or a sub-block as [pje illustrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753722/1256452):

```
{ time ...; } 2>file
```

(the syntax is clumsier with the sub-block as white space and/or semicolons are needed, but it avoids a `fork` system call).

Comment: (This happens no matter how far right you slide the 2>file part, as long as it remains part of the simple-command.) Why so, I did not quite get that?

Comment: @abc: with any of: `time 2>file cmd arg` or `time cmd 2>file arg` or `time cmd arg 2>file`, `time` is handled first, then `cmd`, `arg`, and the `2>file` happen in any order setting up the redirect of `cmd arg`, then `cmd arg` is run (with stderr redirected for the duration of `cmd`, but not for `time` itself).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect the output of `time` and its sub-commands, you could group them as a code block and redirect its stderr to the file:

```
$ { time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync"; } 2> file
```

...which produces:

```
$ cat file
125+0 records in
125+0 records out
64000 bytes (64 kB) copied, 0.000617678 s, 104 MB/s

real        0m0.133s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.020s
```