# How do I prevent bash to use a builtin command?

Tags: bash, sh, built-in

I'm trying to fix a script that use `echo`, that is using the builtin command instead of the command, how can I prevent that?

I know I can do `/bin/echo` to force the usage of that, but I wouldn't like to hardcode the path (for portability).

I thought using something as:

```
$ECHO=`which echo`
$ECHO -e "text\nhere"
```

but `which echo` returns: "echo: shell built-in command".

---

I've ended up defining an `echo` function that uses `env` as @Kenster recommends. This way I don't need to modify the calls to echo in the script.

```
echo() {
  env echo $*
}

# the function is called before the built-in command.
echo -en "text\nhere"
```

Comment: 'the builtin command instead of the command' WTF?

Comment: Why not jsut call it something else ?

Comment: @El_Hoy: Just curious, how is the internal `echo` worse than `/bin/echo` in your scenario?

Comment: There are certain commands (like `echo`) that you can fairly reliably hard-code the path for I believe.

Comment: You can get all the possible paths for a command with `which <command> -a`. Hence, you can for example say: `for c in $(which echo -a); do echo "$c"; type "$c"; done` to see which one is not builtin.

Comment: If portability is your concern, use `printf`, not any form of `echo`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros the non-builtin `echo` support `-e` to add escape sequenses and `-n` to prevent the trailing new line.

Comment: @ForceBru I do not now how to name the binary echo command (`/bin/echo`) over the builtin echo in bash and I'm not native English speaker, should I rephrase it?

Comment: A deleted (and incorrect) answer suggests using the `command` builtin: `command echo ...`. This doesn't work because `command` bypasses shell functions, but doesn't bypass builtin commands. I mention this here for the benefit of those who can't read deleted answers and might try to use `command`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `env` program. Env is a command which launches another program with a possibly modified environment. Because env is a program, it doesn't have access to shell builtins, aliases, and whatnot.

This command will run the echo program, searching for it in your command path:

```
$ env echo foo
```

You can verify this by using `strace` to monitor system calls while running `echo` vs `env echo`:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=process bash -c 'echo foo'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f153fa14700) = 0
foo
exit_group(0)                           = ?

$ strace -f -e trace=process bash -c 'env echo foo'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "env echo foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f474eb2e700) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f60cad15700) = 0
execve("/usr/local/sbin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/sbin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "foo"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f0146906700) = 0
foo
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: I've ended up using your solution, but using a function to simplify implementation: `echo() { env echo $* }` worked great!

Answer (score 15):

You can disable the builtin echo:

```
enable -n echo
```

Now simply doing `echo anything` will run the external version. It only affects the current script process, so you can safely do it in your scripts.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Is `enable` a built-in command? Does it works in `sh`?

Comment: `enable` is a builtin in bash (unless you `enable -n enable`, of course!). It does not work in POSIX `sh` because POSIX has no real notion of builtin vs external.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind when I was `builtin` and `enable` together was `enable -n enable` :D.