# Exploit system() call in C

Tags: c, security, system-calls, exploit

I have the following code in a file named vulnerable.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   gid_t egid = getegid();
   setregid(egid, egid);
   system("echo testing");

   return 0;
}
```

Here are the permissions on the vulnerable executable:

-rwxr-sr-x 1 test cool 8192 Sep 28 2016 vulnerable

In my home directory, I created a new directory called "echotest" and put in a echo.c file and compiled it. The echo.c file just prints out "Exploited!!". I also changed my PATH environment variable to include $HOME/echotest.

Now, when I run vulnerable it should print out "Exploited!" but its not. What am I missing here?

I did a similar test with "cat" and it worked but no luck with echo.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `echo` is often a shell builtin.  If you want it to be exploitable you can change the vulnerable code to this:

```
int main() {
   gid_t egid = getegid();
   setregid(egid, egid);
   system("env echo testing");

   return 0;
}
```

For more about this, see: [How do I prevent bash to use a builtin command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540540/how-do-i-prevent-bash-to-use-a-builtin-command)

Comment: Thanks!! This helps!!