# Force sh shell to use external function instead of built-in

Tags: linux, shell, sh

For some reasons, I want my program to use external functions instead of built-in shell functions (e.g. `echo`). The program has a call to `system()` which use `/bin/sh` to execute the argument.

With `bash` shell I already know that `enable -n <fnc>` can prevent the shell to use the built-in function. However, I couldn't find a similar way for `sh` shell.

Is it possible to do this for `sh`?

Comment: How exactly is `system` being invoked? `system` is likely *already* going to look for an executable named `echo` rather than try to execute a shell builtin.

Comment: @chepner Let's say we have the buiilt-in `echo` and `/bin/echo`. A `system` call `"echo ..."` will use the built-in function. You can test it by setting your own executable `echo` on top of your `$PATH`.

Comment: So ultimately, we're talking abut `sh -c "..."`?

Comment: @chepner Yes. So ultimately I want to make sure that the `echo` call inside `system()` uses exactly my external executable but not the built-in `echo`, without modifying the program (to use the exact path).

Answer (score 1):

To force any shell to use an external executable instead of a builtin command, simply specify it by path:

```
# Use whatever the shell defaults to
echo "Hello World"

# Always use the specified external binary
/bin/echo "Hello World"
```

This behavior is [specified in POSIX 2.9.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> If the command name contains at least one slash, the shell shall execute the utility in a separate utility environment with actions equivalent to calling the execl() function

Comment: This is not what I want. I don't want to modify the program, which includes a call to `system()` with another call to functions e.g. `echo` inside. I want to force the `system()` to use external function e.g. `/bin/echo` instead of the built-in `echo`.

Comment: `system` doesn't care about these things: it's job is to execute a command via the shell, and I'm not aware of a shell that considers avoidance of built-ins for its own sake a necessary feature. In fact, `system` itself doesn't even *control* which shell gets used, so in theory you don't know which commands might be executed as built-ins.

Comment: @chepner I thought `system` uses `execl()` with `"/bin/sh -c"` as an argument. Or am I wrong?

Comment: POSIX just requires `system` to act as if the user ran `sh` using `execl`, without specifying what path is used to find `sh`. It also doesn't impose any requirements on what `sh` actually *is*, though any non-POSIX features in that shell are likely unavailable.

Comment: @EternaLCompleX I'm not sure I understand. How would `enable -n echo` have helped you do this in bash? If you can't modify the `system("..")` call, you wouldn't have been able to insert it. Or if the `system("..")` executed an external script, the fact that `system()` uses `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` doesn't matter because that interpreter is not used for external scripts.

Comment: @thatotherguy You can try `type echo` to see all the options. `enable -n echo` removes shell built-in option out of the list.
By the way, I found another way for my initial purpose so I don't need to care about this problem anymore. Anyway, it is still weird to me that you can prevent built-in functions in `bash` but not in `sh`.

Comment: @EternaLCompleX Only for the current shell instance. If you run `enable -n echo` in a terminal and afterwards run a program with `system("echo Foo")`, then it'll still use builtin echo even when `/bin/sh` is bash. You would have to use `system("enable -n echo; echo Foo")`, but you say "I don't want to modify the program" so that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

It was answered in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29541368/2634595):

Prepend the command with `env`.

```
$ env echo "Hello"
```

`env` is a standalone program, which doesn't have access to the shell builtins, such as `echo`, so it will search for `echo` in the command path.