# Mean of execution time of a program

Tags: bash

I have the following bash code (A.cpp, B.cpp and C.txt are filename in the current directory):

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ A.cpp -o A
g++ B.cpp -o B
Inputfiles=(X Y Z U V)

for j in "${Inputfiles[@]}"
do
   echo $j.txt:
i=1
    while [ $i -le 5 ]
    do
        ./A $j.txt
        ./B C.txt
        echo ""
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    echo ""
done
 
rm -f A B
```

One execution of ./A and ./B is one execution of my program. I run my program 5 times for each input file in the array 'Inputfiles'. I want the average execution time of my program over each input-file. How can I do so?

(Earlier, I tried to add time and clock functions within the A.cpp and B.cpp files, but I am not able to add the execution times of both files to get the execution time of a program.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what average you would like to calculate, I think the code below will serve your purpose.

Some explanations on the additions to your script:

- Lines 6 - 14 declare a function that expects three arguments and updates the accumulated total time, in seconds
- Line 26 initializes variable `total_time`.
- Lines 31, 38, execute programs `A` and `B` respectively. Using bash `time` to collect the execution time. `>/dev/null` "discards" `A`'s and `B`'s outputs. `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout so that `grep` can get `time`'s outputs (a nice explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257724/grep-time-command-output)). `grep real` keeps only the `real` output from `time`, you could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432085/how-to-understand-the-output-of-time-command) for an explanation of `time`'s output and choose the specific time of your interest. `awk {print $2}` keeps only the numeric part of `grep`'s output.
- Lines 32, 39 store the minutes part to the corresponding variable
- Lines 33-34, 40-41 trim the seconds part of `real_time` variable
- Lines 35, 42 accumulate the total time by calling function `accumulate_time`
- Line 46 calculates the average time by dividing with 5
- Converted the while loop to a nested for loop and introduced the `iterations` variable, not necessarily part of the initial question but helps re-usability of the number of iterations

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 # Function that receives three arguments (total time,
  4 # minutes and seconds) and returns the accumulated time in
  5 # seconds
  6 function accumulate_time() {
  7     total_time=$1
  8     minutes=$2
  9     seconds=$3
 10 
 11     accumulated_time_secs=$(echo "$minutes * 60 + $seconds + $total_time" | bc )
 12     echo "$accumulated_time_secs"
 13 
 14 }
 15 
 16 g++ A.cpp -o A
 17 g++ B.cpp -o B
 18 Inputfiles=(X Y Z U V)
 19 
 20 iterations=5
 21 
 22 for j in "${Inputfiles[@]}"
 23 do
 24     echo $j.txt:
 25     # Initialize total_time
 26     total_time=0.0
 27 
 28     for i in $(seq 1 $iterations)
 29     do
 30         # Execute A and capture its real time
 31         real_time=`{ time ./A $j.txt >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`
 32         minutes=${real_time%m*}
 33         seconds=${real_time#*m}
 34         seconds=${seconds%s*}
 35         total_time=$(accumulate_time "$total_time" "$minutes" "$seconds")
 36 
 37         # Execute B and capture its real time
 38         real_time=`{ time ./B C.txt >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`
 39         minutes=${real_time%m*}
 40         seconds=${real_time#*m}
 41         seconds=${seconds%s*}
 42         total_time=$(accumulate_time "$total_time" "$minutes" "$seconds")
 43         echo ""
 44     done
 45 
 46     average_time=$(echo "scale=3; $total_time / $iterations" | bc)
 47     echo "Average time for input file $j is: $average_time"
 48 done
 49 
 50 rm -f A B
```