# Output of time command for a python script

Tags: python, unix, time

I executed a python script on the server with the time command like

```
time python myscript.py
```

The time output was :

```
312.90user 15.57system 2:10:42elapsed 4%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+152440minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

So, does that mean the script took 2 hours 10 minutes and 42 seconds to complete execution ?
Also, what is the meaning of 312.90user and 15.57system ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1 (in your case *elapsed* is equivalent to *real*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply:

"user" is the time the cpu spent running non-system calls in your myscript.py. These are the python codes.

"system" is the time the cpu spent serving system calls made by your myscript.py.  These are code that call the c library functions like open, write, etc., for example.

"elapsed" is the wall clock duration that your program took to run. This is comparable to you measuring the time the program took to run using your wristwatch (if you wear one anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). What are the units for user time and system time ?

Comment: They're the CPU clock ticks. Read http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/times.2.html and http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/time.1.html for the nitty gritty details.

Answer (score 0):

The time is indeed 2 hours and 10 minutes from invocation to termination of your script. 
User shows the CPU time used in user mode and System the cpu time in the kernel.