# Equivalent of Unix time command in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Earlier I was reading a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/556411#556411) on SO and I wondered why it has not been emulated yet in PowerShell.

In unix/linux, we can use the `time` command as a simple benchmark tool.

```
$ time ./script1.sh  

real    0m1.005s  
user    0m0.000s  
sys     0m0.008s
```

In powershell, we can use the `measure-command` similarly:

```
$ Measure-Command {java post_incr}

Days              : 0  
Hours             : 0  
Minutes           : 0  
Seconds           : 1  
Milliseconds      : 18  
Ticks             : 10188003  
TotalDays         : 1.17916701388889E-05  
TotalHours        : 0.000283000083333333  
TotalMinutes      : 0.016980005  
TotalSeconds      : 1.0188003  
TotalMilliseconds : 1018.8003
```

But this is not the same as the `time`, which reports the real, user and sys (See the difference between the three in the linked SO Answer.)

This (`time`) is obviously such a useful little tool. Are there any user written cmdlets for this functionality or is it already in V3 or planned for future releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used both the times provided by `System.Diagnostics.Process` and `GetProcessTimes` to come up with an implementation for `time`:

```
$source=@'

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Timer
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetProcessTimes(IntPtr handle, out long creation, out long exit, out long kernel,
                                                  out long user);

        public static void Time(string file,string args)
        {
            long user,kernel,exit,creation;
            Process proc = null;
            proc = Process.Start(file,args);
            proc.WaitForExit();
            GetProcessTimes(proc.Handle, out creation, out exit, out kernel, out user);
            long real = exit - creation;
            Console.WriteLine("real {0}\nuser {1}\nsys {2}", real / 10000000.0, user/10000000.0,kernel/10000000.0);
        }
    }
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharpVersion3

function time ($scriptblock) {

    $file = "powershell";
    $args = $scriptblock;

    $startInfo = new-object Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $startInfo.FileName = $file;
    $startInfo.Arguments = $args;
    $startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true;
    $startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
    $process = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo);
    $process.WaitForExit();
    write-host $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    write-host real: ($process.ExitTime - $process.StartTime)
    write-host user: $process.UserProcessorTime;
    write-host sys:  $process.PrivilegedProcessorTime;
    write-host using GetProcessTimes
    [Timer]::Time($file,$args)
}

time {sleep 10}
```

It isn't really perfect as the real time comes out as about 11 seconds ( for `sleep 10` ) since I am creating a powershell process and running the command in that. I will see if I can implement a cmdlet or something for this.

Comment: I'm really new to using Windows Powershell, could you explain what I need to do to use your `time` implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Write a C program using the GetProcessTimes function, you could find its documentation in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28VS.85%29.aspx.

In the examples of the book "Windows System Programming" comes a program that use that function to retrieve exactly what you need(Elapsed, Kernel, User times). The program is call "timep.exe" and it can be found in the runX subdirectories (the X comes from the version of Visual Studio used in the compilation) inside the zipped examples archive. Here is the author page from where you could download that archive http://www.jmhartsoftware.com/, of course the source code is also there so you could see exactly how timep.exe works.

Answer (score 2):

Warning, PowerShell ahead.

Some coffee helped me come up with this:

```
function time { $Command = "$args"; Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $Command 2>&1 | out-default} }
```

And if you want it to output nothing, just replace with out-null:

```
function timequiet { $Command = "$args"; Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $Command 2>&1 | out-null} }
```

You use it like this:

```
PS C:\> time sleep 5


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 990
Ticks             : 49906722
TotalDays         : 5,77624097222222E-05
TotalHours        : 0,00138629783333333
TotalMinutes      : 0,08317787
TotalSeconds      : 4,9906722
TotalMilliseconds : 4990,6722



PS C:\>
```

Comment: I think you do not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

The process you are trying to measure may also be forking and running in the background which causes the **Measure-Command** measurement to be cut short. You can use **Start-Process** with the **-Wait** parameter to get the full time measurement that you expect. Here is an example that shows that it takes stackoverflow.com 34 seconds to close an idle connection:

```
$program = 'telnet'
$ArgumentList = 'stackoverflow.com 80'
$WorkingDirectory = 'c:\'
Measure-Command {
   $p = Start-Process -FilePath $program -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -PassThru -WorkingDirectory $WorkingDirectory -NoNewWindow;
   Write-Host $p.ExitCode;
}


#Output:
0


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 34
Milliseconds      : 37
Ticks             : 340370635
TotalDays         : 0.000393947494212963
TotalHours        : 0.00945473986111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.567284391666667
TotalSeconds      : 34.0370635
TotalMilliseconds : 34037.0635
```