# Java GC CMS Collector Times

Tags: java, garbage-collection, concurrent-mark-sweep

We have enabled garbage collection logs for our application. I see some lines where it prints the time of some of the CMS steps. Can anyone explain or point me to some link which explains CMS logs like

9657.238: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 17.199/17.396 secs] [Times: **user=80.61 sys=10.00, real=17.40 secs**]

Comment: A somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1

Answer (score 1):

CMS and its phases are well explained at http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html.

For the times being printed, this is Unix process times, as pointed by Lithium you can read [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) for that.