# how to find scheduling delay for a process in c

Tags: c, linux, scheduling

I have a C program on linux. During execution of my program, I want to make some decisions if the process is facing scheduling delay above a threshold.

Any suggestion on how I find this statistic ?

P.S.: By scheduling delay I mean time spent by the process waiting to be scheduled i.e. time spent in the scheduler queue.

Comment: What do you mean by "scheduling delay"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant how much time the process is spending in scheduler queue, i.e. time spent waiting to be scheduled.

Comment: @Siddharth: you should *edit your question* to improve it instead of answering in comments.

Comment: @Siddharth - Its the ready queue in which the process stands while  
waiting for its turn, and the technical name of scheduling delay    is       
"waiting time".     
Some of the factors on which waiting time depends are :    
1. Scheduling algorithm used.    
2. Number of processes currently running.    
Check out this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265162/the-meaning-of-real-user-and-sys-in-output-of-linux-time-command

Comment: @Abhishek please read the question. I know what factors cause scheduling delays. The question was how to figure out the delay value. Anyway Franco answered that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time()` function allows you to measure the "wall clock" time: http://linux.die.net/man/2/time
On the other side, the `clock()` function allows you to measure the CPU time used by your process: http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock

By subtracting the two, you can get an approximation of what you asked for.

PS: for more accurate measurements (time has a second resolution) you can use `clock_gettime`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

Answer (score 2):

You could set a timer to go off, say every minute, or whatever interval seems appropriate and then gather stats with `getrusage()` and based on those results (the difference between successive values), you could make your decision then