# Which one should i use for benchmark tasks in hadoop user+sys time or total cpu time spent in hadoop job counter?

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, benchmarking, cpu-time

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726388/what-does-cpu-time-for-a-hadoop-job-signify) one statement in a answer written that "same job running over the same data but on one 20 node cluster, then a 200 node cluster.Overall, the same amount of CPU time will be used on both clusters" Can someone explain this ?

I've used `time` command to measure real time. Sometimes i got more cpu time (hadoop counter) than actual real time or vice versa.I know that real time measures actual clock time elapsed and it can be greater or lesser than `user+sys`.

I'm still not getting what total cpu times measures in hadoop.
Regarding time command [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265162/the-meaning-of-real-user-and-sys-in-output-of-linux-time-command?lq=1) answer written it is good to go with user+sys for benchmarks.

1. As `total cpu time taken by process = user+sys` then it should be same as total cpu time of hadoop job counter. But i'm getting different results.
2. Which time should i consider if i'm doing some benchmark kind of tasks in hadoop user+sys or total cpu time spent (hadoop counter)?

note:
In apache [hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-396) benchmark they have considered real time but it can affected by other processes also. So i can not consider real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`same job running over the same data but on one 20 node cluster, then a 200 node cluster.Overall, the same amount of CPU time will be used on both clusters`

This means if a job takes `N` hour on a 20-node cluster, and `M` hours on a 200-node cluster, then `20 * N` should be equal to `M * 200`

real time should be your choice, but as your said above, this value may change accordingly, so you should try at least 3 times, and calculate the average as the final result.

Comment: okay.
Do you have any idea about 1st point why total cpu time in job counter is different than usr+sys?

Comment: I think usr+sys = mapreduce cpu time + cpu some other tasks of usr & sys like allocating memory or accessing hardware etc. am i right?

Comment: @Dhruv Absolutely NOT. `usr + sys` is the running time of the client process not mapreduce framework

Comment: So for the map reduce in case i want to measure cpu time then i should only consider cpu time written in job counter not that i got from time command right?