# Is there a difference in efficiency between pipelined sed invocations and multiple sed expressions?

Tags: regex, performance, bash, sed

I have a question about sed efficiency in bash. I have a pipelined series of sed statements, e.g.:

```
var1="Some string of text"

var2=$(echo "$var1" | sed 's/pattern1/replacement1/g' | sed 's/pattern2/replacement2/g' | sed 's/pattern3/replacement3/g' | sed 's/pattern4/replacement4' | sed 's/pattern5/replacement5/g')
```

Assuming no inputs depend on edited output from an earlier sed pipe, am I better off scripting the above with expression statements instead? For example:

```
var2=$(echo "$var1" | sed -e's/pattern1/replacement1/g' -e's/pattern2/replacement2/g' -e's/pattern3/replacement3/g' -e's/pattern4/replacement4/g' -e's/pattern5/replacement5/g')
```

Is there any efficiency to be gained here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Using multiple expressions will be faster than using multiple pipelines, because you there's additional overhead in creating pipelines and forking sed processes. However, it's rarely enough of a difference to matter in practice.

#### Benchmarks

Using multiple expressions is faster than multiple pipelines, but probably not enough to matter for the average use case. Using your example, the average difference in execution speed was only two-thousandths of a second, which is not enough to get excited about.

```
# Average run with multiple pipelines.
$ time {
    echo "$var1" | 
    sed 's/pattern1/replacement1/g' |
    sed 's/pattern2/replacement2/g' |
    sed 's/pattern3/replacement3/g' |
    sed 's/pattern4/replacement4/g' |
    sed 's/pattern5/replacement5/g'
}
Some string of text

real        0m0.007s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.004s
```

---

```
# Average run with multiple expressions.
$ time {
    echo "$var1" | sed \
    -e 's/pattern1/replacement1/g' \
    -e 's/pattern2/replacement2/g' \
    -e 's/pattern3/replacement3/g' \
    -e 's/pattern4/replacement4/g' \
    -e 's/pattern5/replacement5/g'
}
Some string of text

real        0m0.005s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.000s
```

Granted, this isn't testing against a large input file, thousands of input files, or running in a loop with tens of thousands of iterations. Still, it seems safe to say that the difference is small enough to be irrelevant for most common situations.

Uncommon situations are a different story. In such cases, benchmarking will help you determine whether replacing pipes with in-line expressions is a valuable optimization *for that use case*.

Comment: N.B. `/pattern/s//replacement/g` is faster and more efficient.

Comment: @potong, I have no trouble imagining that `/p/ s//r/g` is faster than `s/p/r/g` (particularly if the input is a long string with many replacements and no line breaks) but on the other hand I also have no trouble imagining that `s/p/r/g` might be handled exactly like `/p/ s//r/g`, and also expect that if lines are short and several RE's intermixed it will make no practical difference.  Do you have measurements to prove “faster and more efficient” claim, or a sed code snippet?

Comment: I also made a few tests, and it seems to me using multiple sed invocations results in shorter real time on my quad-core system. Of course the CPU usage is much higher, but sometimes shorter time is all you want.

Comment: @YongweiWu You are correct. [I present benchmarks in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595148/) that show that pipes are faster on multi-core systems.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the overhead in sed tends to be processing regular expressions but you're processing the same number of regular expressions in each of your examples.

Consider that the operating system needs to construct std and stdout for each element of the pipe.  Sed also takes memory in your system, and the OS must allocate that memory for each instance of sed -- whether that's one instance or four.

Here's my assessment:

```
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10000 | time sed 's/1/_/g' | time sed 's/2/_/g' | time sed 's/3/_/g' | time sed 's/4/_/g' >/dev/null 
        2.38 real         0.84 user         0.01 sys
        2.38 real         0.84 user         0.01 sys
        2.39 real         0.85 user         0.01 sys
        2.39 real         0.85 user         0.01 sys
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10000 | time sed 's/1/_/g;s/2/_/g;s/3/_/g;s/4/_/g' >/dev/null
        2.71 real         2.57 user         0.02 sys
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10000 | time sed 's/1/_/g;s/2/_/g;s/3/_/g;s/4/_/g' >/dev/null
        2.71 real         2.56 user         0.02 sys
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10000 | time sed 's/1/_/g;s/2/_/g;s/3/_/g;s/4/_/g' >/dev/null
        2.71 real         2.57 user         0.02 sys
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10000 | time sed 's/1/_/g;s/2/_/g;s/3/_/g;s/4/_/g' >/dev/null
        2.74 real         2.57 user         0.02 sys
$ dc
.84 2* .85 2* + p
3.38
$
```

And since 3.38 > 2.57, les time is taken up if you use a single instance of sed.

Comment: Yes, there is more overhead in multiple sed invocations. However, if we care more about real time, using several sed invocations can be more beneficial on a multi-processor/core system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You'll avoid the overhead of starting sed anew each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably measure the efficiency to gauge the different. Perhaps using `time` command. Empirically, -e will be more efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in ghoti's answer, your examples have the same number of regular expressions in either case (separate invocations of `sed` vs a series of `-e` expressions), but OS overhead includes pipeline and process setup and memory allocation for each instance of `sed`.  For a handful of invocations the OS overhead isn't be worth worrying about, but if the number is thousands or more, it might be.

Anyhow, computer efficiency aside, programmer efficiency often is a more important concern.  Both ways shown so far are clumsy and slow to enter.  It is easier (at least with GNU sed) to use a semicolon-separated `sed` command list instead of numerous separate `-e` strings.  An example follows.

```
$ var1="Some p1 string p2 of p3 text p4 etc"
$ var2=$(echo "$var1" | sed 's/p1/a1/g; s/p2/b2/g; s/p3/c3/g; s/p4/d4/; s/p5/e5/g')
$ echo $var2
Some a1 string b2 of c3 text d4 etc
```

Unfortunately I don't see semicolon-as-sed-command-separator listed in `sed` documentation, and don't know whether this is available in other versions than GNU sed.

Comment: [POSIX sed allows a semicolon after the `s` command if you do not use the `w` flag.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: @FWDekker, ok, I see that that ref (re POSIX sed) says "when an s editing command is used with the w flag, following it with [semicolon sequence] produces undefined results".   But because my suggested sequence has no w flags, it should work with POSIX as well as GNU sed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most other answers give logical arguments but don't have evidence to back them up.
Let's do some benchmarks.

I'll show that **a chain of pipes is the faster method on multi-core systems**.
Naturally, this only holds for sufficiently large inputs (= several thousands of lines).

### Setup

Let's use a setup similar to [ghoti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641389/).
We take the output of `shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000`, which picks 1 000 000 different numbers from the range 1 to 10 000 000, and then use `sed` to replace the digits 1 through 9 with a `_`.
Choosing such a large number of lines means that unrelated overheads and interference are minimised.

We use [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) for benchmarking.
It will repeat the command several times and take the average running time.

We will compare the following three methods.
We write to `/dev/null` because we don't care about the speed of writing to stdout.

```bash
# pipes
shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' | sed -e 's/2/_/g' | sed -e 's/3/_/g' | sed -e 's/4/_/g' | sed -e 's/5/_/g' | sed -e 's/6/_/g' | sed -e 's/7/_/g' | sed -e 's/8/_/g' | sed -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null

# single_sed
shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' -e 's/2/_/g' -e 's/3/_/g' -e 's/4/_/g' -e 's/5/_/g' -e 's/6/_/g' -e 's/7/_/g' -e 's/8/_/g' -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null

# single_script
shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g; s/2/_/g; s/3/_/g; s/4/_/g; s/5/_/g; s/6/_/g; s/7/_/g; s/8/_/g; s/9/_/g' > /dev/null
```

### Results

```bash
hyperfine \
    "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' | sed -e 's/2/_/g' | sed -e 's/3/_/g' | sed -e 's/4/_/g' | sed -e 's/5/_/g' | sed -e 's/6/_/g' | sed -e 's/7/_/g' | sed -e 's/8/_/g' | sed -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null" \
    "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' -e 's/2/_/g' -e 's/3/_/g' -e 's/4/_/g' -e 's/5/_/g' -e 's/6/_/g' -e 's/7/_/g' -e 's/8/_/g' -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null" \
    "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g; s/2/_/g; s/3/_/g; s/4/_/g; s/5/_/g; s/6/_/g; s/7/_/g; s/8/_/g; s/9/_/g' > /dev/null"

Benchmark 1: pipes
  Time (mean ± σ):     314.0 ms ±   8.3 ms    [User: 2060.1 ms, System: 55.6 ms]
  Range (min … max):   297.4 ms … 326.4 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark 2: single_sed
  Time (mean ± σ):     935.1 ms ±  19.5 ms    [User: 972.1 ms, System: 17.0 ms]
  Range (min … max):   901.8 ms … 959.3 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark 3: single_script
  Time (mean ± σ):     920.6 ms ±  13.8 ms    [User: 962.6 ms, System: 11.3 ms]
  Range (min … max):   901.8 ms … 939.7 ms    10 runs
 
Summary
  pipes ran
    2.93 ± 0.09 times faster than single_script
    2.98 ± 0.10 times faster than single_sed
```

Clearly, `pipes` is the fastest method here, being almost three times as fast as the other two methods.
Note that we're comparing "[real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/)" here, which is the wall-clock time, which is probably what you're most interested in.

Why is `pipes` fastest?
Because without pipes, `sed` runs on a single core, which has to do all the work;
each pattern is executed on each line in sequence.
But if we use pipes, the output of the first `sed` can be piped to the second `sed`, which runs on a separate core, and can therefore immediately start with its pattern, while the first `sed` is simultaneously working on its second line.
The power of concurrency means that the first input line may already have been processed by all nine `sed`s before the first `sed` is even complete with its own lines!

We can test this hypothesis by re-running the experiment on a single core.

#### Single-core results

We can force the benchmarks to run on a single core using [`taskset`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html).

```bash
taskset --cpu-list 1 \
    hyperfine \
    -n pipes         "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' | sed -e 's/2/_/g' | sed -e 's/3/_/g' | sed -e 's/4/_/g' | sed -e 's/5/_/g' | sed -e 's/6/_/g' | sed -e 's/7/_/g' | sed -e 's/8/_/g' | sed -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null" \
    -n single_sed    "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g' -e 's/2/_/g' -e 's/3/_/g' -e 's/4/_/g' -e 's/5/_/g' -e 's/6/_/g' -e 's/7/_/g' -e 's/8/_/g' -e 's/9/_/g' > /dev/null" \
    -n single_script "shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 | sed -e 's/1/_/g; s/2/_/g; s/3/_/g; s/4/_/g; s/5/_/g; s/6/_/g; s/7/_/g; s/8/_/g; s/9/_/g' > /dev/null"

Benchmark 1: pipes
  Time (mean ± σ):      1.322 s ±  0.014 s    [User: 1.259 s, System: 0.062 s]
  Range (min … max):    1.300 s …  1.346 s    10 runs
 
Benchmark 2: single_sed
  Time (mean ± σ):     955.4 ms ±   7.9 ms    [User: 932.5 ms, System: 22.4 ms]
  Range (min … max):   947.7 ms … 976.2 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark 3: single_script
  Time (mean ± σ):     952.7 ms ±   4.9 ms    [User: 934.7 ms, System: 17.6 ms]
  Range (min … max):   944.1 ms … 959.4 ms    10 runs
 
Summary
  single_script ran
    1.00 ± 0.01 times faster than single_sed
    1.39 ± 0.02 times faster than pipes
```

In this case, the `pipes` method is slower than the other methods because of the inherent overhead in creating multiple processes.
This overhead was also present in the multi-core case, but the overhead was spread out over different cores, and the advantage of concurrency more than made up for this overhead.

If your inputs are very small, the overhead of spawning new processes will outweigh the concurrency advantage, and `pipes` will be slower even on multi-core machines.
I adjusted the above parameters, and found that, on my machine, `pipes` and `single_sed` are approximately equally fast when given 2000 lines of input, both taking 2 milliseconds to transform all 2000 lines.
This equilibrium will differ depending on your machine and the patterns you give to `sed`, but overall, larger inputs benefit more from concurrency.