# multiple sed commands: when semicolon, when pipeline?

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

When I construct a complicated operation in sed, I often start with

```
cat infile | sed 'expression1' | sed 'expr2' ...
```

and then optimize that into

```
cat infile | sed 'expr1;expr2;expr3' | sed 'expr4' | sed 'expr5;expr6' ...
```

What guidelines are there for which expressions can be combined with semicolons into a single command?
So far, I just ad hoc combine `s///`'s, and don't combine `//d`'s.

(The optimization is for running it tens of millions of times.  Yes, it's [measurably faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641333/is-there-a-difference-in-efficiency-between-pipelined-sed-invocations-and-multip).)

(Posted here instead of on superuser.com, because that has 20x fewer questions about sed.)

Comment: wrt `When I construct a complicated operation in sed` - don't do that! sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. The result will be clearer, faster, more portable, more robust, easier to maintain, and better in every other way than a complicated set of sed operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to avoid multiple `sed` with

```
sed -f mycmd.awk
```

Where `mycmd.awk` will contain each sed command be listed on a separate line.

As per `man sed`:

> `-f` command_file
>   Append the editing commands found in the file command_file to the list of commands.  The editing commands should each be listed on a separate line.

Comment: While you definitely *can* call your sed script `mycmd.awk`, I think it's cruel for anybody who'll ever have to understand it ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. It does show his mind his leaning in the right direction though ;-).

Answer (score 6):

The operation that you're carrying out is fundamentally different in each case.

When you "combine" sed commands using a pipe, the whole file is processed by every invocation of sed. This incurs the cost of launching a separate process for every part of your pipeline.

When you use a semicolon-separated list of commands, each command is applied in turn to every line in the file, using a single instance of sed.

Depending on the commands you're using, the output of these two things could be very different!

If you don't like using semicolons to separate commands, I would propose another option: use `sed -e 'expr1' -e 'expr2' -e 'expr3' file`. Alternatively, many tools including sed support `-f` to pass a file containing commands. You can put each command on a newline instead of using semicolons for clarity.

Comment: Using a pipe does *not* mean that the command on the receiving end of the pipe is delayed starting (or delayed starting to process data) until the command on the sending end is finished / closes its pipe end.  Something like that would happen with separate `sed` commands separated by semicolons, but not with a pipe.

Comment: @John good point, I removed that part from my answer. I'm starting to doubt the part about the output being different now I think about it!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `s` and `d` can coexist peacefully. It's when the different commands interact with each other that you may have to break down and use separate scripts, or switch to a richer language with variables etc.

For example, a `sed` script which adds thousands separators to numbers which lack them should probably be kept completely separate from other processing. The modularity is probably more important than any possible efficiency gains in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

> What guidelines are there for which expressions can be combined with semicolons into a single command? So far, I just ad hoc combine s///'s, and don't combine //d's.

`sed` has many more commands than just `s` and `d`.  If those are the only ones you're using, though, then you can join as many as you like in the same `sed` run.  The result will be the same as for a pipeline of multiple single-command `sed`s.  If you're going to do that, however, then consider either using a command file, as @anubhava suggested, or giving each independent expression via its own `-e` argument; either one is much clearer than a single expression consisting of multiple semicolon-separated commands.

Even if you use other commands, for the most part you will get the same result from performing a sequence of commands via a single `sed` process as you do by performing the same commands in the same order via separate `sed` processes.  The main exceptions I can think of involve commands that are necessarily dependent on one another, such as labels and branches; commands manipulating the hold space and those around them; commands grouped within braces (`{}`); and the `p` command under `sed -n`.

With that said, `sed` programs get very cryptic very fast.  If you're writing a complicated transformation then consider carefully taking @EdMorton's advice and writing the whole thing as a (single) `awk` program instead of one or several `sed` programs.