# Track the time a command takes in UNIX/LINUX?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal

In UNIX/LINUX, is there an easy way to track the time a command takes?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Yes, use `time <command>`, such as

```
time ls
```

Consult `man time` for more options. [Link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time).

Comment: And, the meaning of real/user/sys times is nicely covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)

Comment: This answer is inaccurate for bash users on linux. The manpage documents the Gnu time command, but time is a builtin in bash, which doesn't have all the options documented there.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
/usr/bin/time
```

instead that the time builtin in the bash: it is more configurable AFAIK.

```
e.g. /usr/bin/time --format=' \n---- \nelapsed time is %e'ls
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is default.  This was the case on the CentOS 6, CentOS 7 and Debian 8 systems I checked:
`user@host:~$ which time
/usr/bin/time`

Looks to be version 1.7 of GNU time.

Comment: @Toby: Even though "which" says it's /usr/bin/time, in bash, the builtin overrides that. If I do `time -f "\t%E real" ls` in bash, I get an error, but it works if I do `/usr/bin/time -f "\t%E real" ls`.

Comment: You're right.  That's very interesting and enlightening.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `which`. Use `type -a`:
`$ which time
/usr/bin/time
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time`

Comment: Note that using `/usr/bin/time` prevents you from using bash aliases. The bash builtin `time` is needed for that, else you'll get the error `cannot run my_alias: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how a `sleep` of one second looks like, timed with `time`:

```
$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `time` is built-in in the bash but it can also be installed on most distros by installing the package "time" (apt install time) and must be accessed by doing `/usr/bin/time`.

Using `/usr/bin/time` offers more convenient options like specifying a format:

```
time --format="Duration: %e seconds" sleep 3
```