# Understanding GC logs - app thread were stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, garbage

Taking a look at GC log file, its self-explanatory to understand that app was stopped for 0.0011450 seconds (stop-the-world)

```
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0011450 seconds
```

However, please help me understand whether below lines also means stop-the-world? Or it just shows the time taken by each thread, what does real=TIME means (last line below)?

```
Finished work stealing in 3th thread: 13.706 sec
Finished work stealing in 2th thread: 17.325 sec
Finished work stealing in 4th thread: 17.052 sec
Finished work stealing in 0th thread: 17.325 sec
Finished work stealing in 1th thread: 17.324 sec
2015-08-19T03:20:32.882-0400: 321985.669: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 20.519/20.624 secs] (CMS-concurrent-mark yielded 6 times)
 [Times: user=138.91 sys=0.10, real=20.62 secs]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs) is the first result when googling "CMS-concurrent-mark" and explains the various CMS phases.

Running the log through [GCviewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) would also list STW and non-STW phases separately.

And since you already have turned on application-stopped-time logging the lack of a stopped time logging entry should be a dead giveaway whether it's a STW-pause or not.

> what does real=TIME means (last line below)?

This output is equivalent to output you would get from [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) for example. Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/1362755). Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669328/1362755) specifically referring to CMS logs.