# Interpreting Linux time command result for a multi-threaded program (%CPU > 100)

Tags: linux, time, benchmarking, blast

I want to benchmark BLAST running time on my server so I started the `time` command. 
The server has 16 CPUs and I was running the BLAST 16 threaded. There may have been other applications running in parallel while my analysis was taking place.

The output is following:

```
184255.45user 458.23system 6:37:54elapsed 773%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 83504272maxresident)k
294680inputs+10029344outputs (1799major+149694417minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Interpreting user time as the amount of seconds CPU spent running my application I get more than the total time.  I have seen people tell that I should divide the time with %CPU, but then I get just 3 minutes, and that is unrealistic for BLAST and input of the size I put into it.

The information I need is the user time, but I am not sure how to interpret it.

Any suggestions on the interpretation of the result?

Comment: Totally tangential (but possibly related) question: Is this a cluster?

Comment: You're doing the math wrong.  184255.45 ÷ 773% = 23800, or about 400 minutes.

Comment: Just for the record (additionally to the comment by @DietrichEpp ): You have to divide percentages by `100`, otherwise you can't do calculations with them. `184,255.45s ÷ (773% ÷ 100) ≈ 23,836.41s` `23,836.41s ÷ 60 ≈ 400min`

Answer (score 4):

From the manpage (and taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/338035/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-the-time-command)):

> ```
> The default format is:
>
>     %Uuser %Ssystem %Eelapsed %PCPU (%Xtext+%Ddata %Mmax)k
>     %Iinputs+%Ooutputs (%Fmajor+%Rminor)pagefaults %Wswaps
> ```

So, *184255* seconds spent in userspace, *458* seconds in kernelspace, *6 hours, 37 minutes and 54 seconds* elapsed "real" time.

So as Dietrich Epp pointed out in his comment, and looking at the elapsed time, they match, *6:37:53* is *397.8833* minutes.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) a nice explanation of the difference between `user/system/real(elapsed)` time:

> Real is wall clock time - time from start to finish of the call. This is all elapsed time including time slices used by other processes
>   and time the process spends blocked (for example if it is waiting for
>   I/O to complete).
>
> User is the amount of CPU time spent in user-mode code (outside the kernel) within the process. This is only actual CPU time used in
>   executing the process. Other processes and time the process spends
>   blocked do not count towards this figure.
>
> Sys is the amount of CPU time spent in the kernel within the process. This means executing CPU time spent in system calls within
>   the kernel, as opposed to library code, which is still running in
>   user-space. Like 'user', this is only CPU time used by the process.
>   See below for a brief description of kernel mode (also known as
>   'supervisor' mode) and the system call mechanism.