# Ruby .reject! vs .delete_if

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, hash

Being new to Ruby, I have a question about the difference between the .reject! and .delete_if methods when dealing with hashes and arrays. If just wanting to get rid of certain objects, is there functionally any difference between the methods? And reason to use one over the other?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I have read the documentation...I guess I should have been more clear in my original question. I was wondering more about differences in efficiency. Do they operate differently in how they delete items? (Again, ignoring return value. I understand that is a difference. Thanks!)

Comment: @rid so does `delete_if`

Comment: Haven't you tried reading the documentation? It is quite explicit about this: [`Hash#reject!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject-21) and [`Array#reject!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) is pretty clear about this.

The difference is that if `reject!` does not change the array, it returns `nil`.  `delete_if` will return the unchanged array.

Comment: @JanDvorak "...but returns nil if no changes were made."  Looks like the documentation includes the return value to me.

Comment: Oops, misread. Deleting my answer and upvoting yours. Also, tested in jRuby 1.7.3 (`["a"].delete_if{false}` returns the array while `["a"].reject!{false}` returns `nil`)

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks. I had seen that in the documentation, but I guess I was asking more in terms of efficiency. Ignoring return value, I'm wondering if one is more efficient at deleting items?

Comment: I would recommend the http://ruby-doc.org as a link to documentation instead of the http://apidock.com you linked.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html for the hashes,
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html for the arrays.

Comment: @ExplosionPills : The explanation is not correct! `reject!` **does** change the array, as you can see by doing `a=[1,2,3,4]; a.reject! {|i|  i==2 }; puts a`.

Comment: @user1934428 you might have misread; I said _if_ `reject!` does not change the array... Try `a=[1,2,3,4]; a.reject! {|i| i == 5 };`

Comment: Right! I now see it.

Answer (score 72):

- `reject` - create a new array without elements that match and return the new array
- `delete_if` - delete elements that match from **current** array and return the array
- `reject!` - delete elements that match from **current** array. Return the array if something was rejected, or `nil` when none.

Comment: Thank you for the organized answer. Makes it so much easier than parsing what other people write inline.

Comment: `reject` always returns an *Array*, while `delete_if` and `reject!` returns the original object (which could have been a *Set*, for example).

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr: `delete_if` seems slightly faster. However, the main consideration for choosing a method is the difference in the return value, as pointed out in the other answers.

Since you clarified that your question is concerning efficiency, I did a few tests:

```
> time { (1..100000).to_a.reject!{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  0.390000   0.000000   0.390000 (  0.394596)
> time { (1..100000).to_a.delete_if{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.399122)

> time { (1..200000).to_a.reject!{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  1.650000   0.000000   1.650000 (  1.657927)
> time { (1..200000).to_a.delete_if{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  1.630000   0.010000   1.640000 (  1.637719)

> time { (1..300000).to_a.reject!{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  3.700000   0.000000   3.700000 (  3.717206)
> time { (1..300000).to_a.delete_if{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  3.660000   0.000000   3.660000 (  3.686213)

> time { (1..400000).to_a.reject!{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  7.320000   0.020000   7.340000 (  7.361767)
> time { (1..400000).to_a.delete_if{ |n| n % 5 == 0 } }
  7.190000   0.020000   7.210000 (  7.239549)
```

So, looks like that beyond a certain size `delete_if` is slightly faster.
`time` is defined as:

```
def time(&block)
  puts Benchmark.measure(&block)
end
```

The numbers represent user CPU time, system CPU time, the sum of the user and system CPU times, and the elapsed real time, respectively. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) an explanation of their meanings.
Note that as in every benchmark, YMMV, and you should test on your specific workflows rather than my contrived example of removing numbers that are multiples of 5.

Comment: The concern about efficiency of two similar built-ins is a red herring. And you didn't really prove anything with this test.

Comment: Why is it a "red herring"? The OP "was wondering more about differences in efficiency"

Comment: It's a red herring because nobody should choose between the two methods based on fractions of a second of execution speed. I would really hate to see the code of someone who made this the primary determination of their coding style.

Comment: Right, but it's irrelevant, since the OP has read the docs and is fully aware of the semantic difference. Nevertheless, s/he asked specifically about **efficiency** rather than general guidelines when to use what.

Comment: Maybe we agree to disagree? I believe if an OP has a misplaced concern then it is our duty to point it out.

Comment: And I've removed my downvote. I still feel that the real answer is no, there is no significant difference and certainly no performance-related reason to choose between the two. I challenge anyone to find a real-world example where it makes any real difference.