# Conclude for performance update with time command?

Tags: python, performance, time, real-time

I read about real/user/sys in this thread [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)

For my Python program I get these values:

> real   1m0.910s
>
> user   0m15.615s
>
> sys    0m8.885s

Since my `real` time is way higher then `user` can I conclude that there is space for a performance upgrade (e.g. with parallelism)??

Comment: It might just mean that your process was suspended a long time. It means your process only took 15 seconds of CPU time, so that's almost certainly the wrong place to optimize.

Comment: Can I somehow get more information about why is was suspended so long?